# How to select the first, second, or third element with a given class name?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

How can I select a certain element in a list of elements? I have the following:

```html
<div class="myclass">my text1</div>
<!-- some other code follows -->
<div>
    <p>stuff</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>more stuff</p>
</div>
<p>
    <span>Hello World</span>
</p>
<div class="myclass">my text2</div>
<!-- some other code follows -->
<div>
    <p>stuff</p>
</div>
<p>
    <span>Hello World</span>
</p>
<input type=""/>
<div class="myclass">my text3</div>
<!-- some other code follows -->
<div>
    <p>stuff</p>
</div>
<footer>The end</footer>
```

I have the CSS class `div.myclass {doing things}` that applies to all, obviously, but I also wanted to be able to select the first, second, or third div of class `.myclass` like this, **regardless of where they are in the markup**:

```css
div.myclass:first {color:#000;} 
div.myclass:second {color:#FFF;} 
div.myclass:third {color:#006;}
```

Almost like the jQuery index selection `.eq( index )`, which is what I am using currently, but I need a no-script alternative.

To be specific, I am looking for pseudo selectors, not things like adding another class or using IDs to make things work.

Comment: How about the CSS's **[nth-child](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild)**, did you try that....? **Note:** This works in modern browsers only

Comment: That note seems to be synonymous to "No IE".

Comment: @extraneon: Yup, you got it right :)

Comment: This would not work since there are no uniform parent containers, which is why i wanted to select based on class name occurrence rather. I would have to look at each and every instance and find out the parent tag,id or class in order to select the child. Doing which does not give me uniformity and is difficult to read and would also need to be updated if parent objects/attributes change.

Comment: nth-child is now supported by IE 9+.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You probably finally realized this between posting this question and today, but the very nature of selectors makes it impossible to navigate through hierarchically unrelated HTML elements.

Or, to put it simply, since you said in your comment that

> there are no uniform parent containers

... it's just not possible with selectors alone, without modifying the markup in some way as shown by the other answers.

You *have* to use the jQuery `.eq()` solution.

Comment: Yes, i was aware of css's hierarchical issues but it was wishful thinking i guess that motivated me to post this que anyways.

Comment: You don't have to use jQuery's `.eq()` functions, you can do it just fine just plain JavaScript: `document.querySelector(".myclass")[n]` where n is the number you want

Comment: @Zach Saucier: This was 5 years ago. (... 4 and a half.)

Comment: @ZachSaucier * ahem * You're missing "_All_ " at your query selector 

Comment: Example: document.querySelectorAll(".class")[1]

Answer (score 94):

use nth-child(item number)
EX

```
<div class="parent_class">
    <div class="myclass">my text1</div>
    some other code+containers...

    <div class="myclass">my text2</div>
    some other code+containers...

    <div class="myclass">my text3</div>
    some other code+containers...
</div>
.parent_class:nth-child(1) { };
.parent_class:nth-child(2) { };
.parent_class:nth-child(3) { };
```

OR

:nth-of-type(item number)
same your code

```
.myclass:nth-of-type(1) { };
.myclass:nth-of-type(2) { };
.myclass:nth-of-type(3) { };
```

Comment: -1 You (and everyone who upvoted this answer) seem to have misunderstood the "some other code+containers" part. It's not literally that text. It's other *elements*. If you have any other div elements among these ones, your selectors will stop working altogether.

Comment: @BoltClock, your comment initially struck me as misguided...until I investigated further. See my "answer" on this same page that demonstrates the problem that (I think) you were trying to point out. Thank you for your expertise.

Answer (score 26):

This isn't so much an answer as a non-answer, i.e. an example showing why [one of the highly voted answers above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13888801/5218951) is actually wrong.

I thought that answer looked good. In fact, it gave me what I was looking for: `:nth-of-type` which, for my situation, worked. (So, thanks for that, @Bdwey.)

I initially read the comment by @BoltClock (which says that the answer is essentially wrong) and dismissed it, as I had checked my use case, and it worked. Then I realized @BoltClock had a reputation of 300,000+(!) and has a profile where he claims to be a CSS guru. Hmm, I thought, maybe I should look a little closer.

Turns out as follows: `div.myclass:nth-of-type(2)` does NOT mean "the 2nd instance of div.myclass". Rather, it means "the 2nd instance of div, and it must also have the 'myclass' class". That's an important distinction when there are intervening `div`s between your `div.myclass` instances.

It took me some time to get my head around this. So, to help others figure it out more quickly, I've written an example which I believe demonstrates the concept more clearly than a written description: I've hijacked the `h1`, `h2`, `h3` and `h4` elements to essentially be `div`s. I've put an `A` class on some of them, grouped them in 3's, and then colored the 1st, 2nd and 3rd instances blue, orange and green using `h?.A:nth-of-type(?)`. (But, if you're reading carefully, you should be asking "the 1st, 2nd and 3rd instances of what?"). I also interjected a dissimilar (i.e. different `h` level) or similar (i.e. same `h` level) un-classed element into some of the groups.

Note, in particular, the last grouping of 3. Here, an un-classed `h3` element is inserted between the first and second `h3.A` elements. In this case, no 2nd color (i.e. orange) appears, and the 3rd color (i.e. green) shows up on the 2nd instance of `h3.A`. This shows that the `n` in `h3.A:nth-of-type(n)` is counting the `h3`s, not the `h3.A`s.

Well, hope that helps. And thanks, @BoltClock.

```css
div {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  border: red solid 1px;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  font-size: 12pt;
  margin: 5px;
}

h1.A:nth-of-type(1),
h2.A:nth-of-type(1),
h3.A:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: cyan;
}

h1.A:nth-of-type(2),
h2.A:nth-of-type(2),
h3.A:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: orange;
}

h1.A:nth-of-type(3),
h2.A:nth-of-type(3),
h3.A:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 class="A">h1.A #1</h1>
  <h1 class="A">h1.A #2</h1>
  <h1 class="A">h1.A #3</h1>
</div>

<div>
  <h2 class="A">h2.A #1</h2>
  <h4>this intervening element is a different type, i.e. h4 not h2</h4>
  <h2 class="A">h2.A #2</h2>
  <h2 class="A">h2.A #3</h2>
</div>

<div>
  <h3 class="A">h3.A #1</h3>
  <h3>this intervening element is the same type, i.e. h3, but has no class</h3>
  <h3 class="A">h3.A #2</h3>
  <h3 class="A">h3.A #3</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Haha my profile is a little tongue-in-cheek I'll admit... but that's not even the problem with the answer I commented on - the problem is that it takes the "some other code+containers..." text completely literally, when it's obviously referring to other actual intervening elements, which would have interfered with the :nth-child() matches (which, looking at it again, are all written wrongly for a different reason altogether). But as you have discovered, :nth-of-type() is a different beast...

Comment: Also, more on :nth-child(), :nth-of-type(), and arbitrary selectors in these other answers of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector/5546296#5546296 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657555/what-is-the-difference-between-first-child-and-first-of-type/24657721#24657721

Answer (score 23):

Yes, you can do this.  For example, to style the td tags that make up the different columns of a table you could do something like this:

```
table.myClass tr > td:first-child /* First column */
{
  /* some style here */
}
table.myClass tr > td:first-child+td /* Second column */
{
  /* some style here */
}
table.myClass tr > td:first-child+td+td /* Third column */
{
  /* some style here */
}
```

Comment: maybe nth child would be a better solution: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-child-pseudo

Comment: -1 The question asks about picking the nth of a set of unrelated elements with class names, not the nth child.

Comment: changing `+ td` to `~ .someclassname`

Answer (score 11):

Perhaps using the "~" selector of CSS?

```
.myclass {
    background: red;
}

.myclass~.myclass {
    background: yellow;
}

.myclass~.myclass~.myclass {
    background: green;
}
```

See my example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/netsi1964/wvwg5ywp/)

Comment: This only works for sibling elements and not what the OP is asking for (regardless of markup)

Comment: But it was handy in writing a React Jest unit test, where pseudo-selectors don't work. So, thanks, Netsi1964

Answer (score 1):

In the future (perhaps) you will be able to use `:nth-child(an+b of s)`

In your case it would be `:nth-child(-n+3 of .myclass)`

Actually, browser support for the “of” filter is very limited. Only Safari seems to support the syntax.

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/

Comment: This seems not an answer as OP is trying to select an element directly based on class name, not a child pf the element. See his comment: "
This would not work since there are no uniform parent containers, which is why i wanted to select based on class name occurrence rather"