# Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to select every nth child *that matches (or does not match) an arbitrary selector*?  For example, I want to select every odd table row, but within a subset of the rows:

```css
table.myClass tr.row:nth-child(odd) {
  ...
}
```

```html
<table class="myClass">
  <tr>
    <td>Row
  <tr class="row"> <!-- I want this -->
    <td>Row
  <tr class="row">
    <td>Row
  <tr class="row"> <!-- And this -->
    <td>Row
</table>
```

But `:nth-child()` just seems to count all the `tr` elements regardless of whether or not they're of the "row" class, so I end up with the one *even* "row" element instead of the two I'm looking for. The same thing happens with `:nth-of-type()`.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: As of October 2021 nth-child(n of S) is specified (where S is a selector) but as far as I can ascertain is currently implemented only in Safari, See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304163) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=854148) both have open issues to implement `:nth-child(An+B of S)`.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

[The support of the new syntax](https://caniuse.com/css-nth-child-of) is pretty good now so you can use:

```css
table.myClass tr:nth-child(odd of .row)
```

---

This is a very common problem that arises due to a misunderstanding of how `:nth-child(An+B)` and `:nth-of-type()` work.

In Selectors Level 3, the [`:nth-child()` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#nth-child-pseudo) counts elements among *all* of their siblings under the same parent. It does not count only the siblings that match the rest of the selector.

Similarly, the [`:nth-of-type()` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#nth-of-type-pseudo) counts siblings sharing the same element type, which refers to the tag name in HTML, and not the rest of the selector.

This also means that if all the children of the same parent are of the same element type, for example in the case of a table body whose only children are `tr` elements or a list element whose only children are `li` elements, then `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` will behave identically, i.e. for every value of An+B, `:nth-child(An+B)` and `:nth-of-type(An+B)` will match the same set of elements.

In fact, all simple selectors in a given compound selector, including pseudo-classes such as `:nth-child()` and `:not()`, work *independently* of one another, rather than looking at the *subset* of elements that are matched by the rest of the selector.

This also implies that **there is no notion of order among simple selectors within each individual compound selector**<sup>1</sup>, which means for example the following two selectors are equivalent:

```
table.myClass tr.row:nth-child(odd)
table.myClass tr:nth-child(odd).row
```

Translated to English, they both mean:

> Select any `tr` element that matches all of the following independent conditions:
>
> - it is an odd-numbered child of its parent;
> - it has the class "row"; and
> - it is a descendant of a `table` element that has the class "myClass".

<sup>(you'll notice my use of an unordered list here, just to drive the point home)</sup>

Selectors level 4 seeks to rectify this limitation by allowing [`:nth-child(An+B of S)`](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#nth-child-pseudo)<sup>2</sup> to accept an arbitrary selector argument S, again due to how selectors operate independently of one another in a compound selector as dictated by the existing selector syntax. So in your case, it would look like this:

```
table.myClass tr:nth-child(odd of .row)
```

You can also use a script to filter elements and apply styles or extra class names accordingly. For example, the following is a common workaround using jQuery (assuming there is only one row group populated with `tr` elements within the table):

```
$('table.myClass').each(function() {
  // Note that, confusingly, jQuery's filter pseudos are 0-indexed
  // while CSS :nth-child() is 1-indexed
  $('tr.row:even').addClass('odd');
});
```

With the corresponding CSS:

```
table.myClass tr.row.odd {
  ...
}
```

If you're using automated testing tools such as Selenium or scraping HTML with tools like BeautifulSoup, many of these tools allow XPath as an alternative:

```
//table[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' myClass ')]//tr[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' row ')][position() mod 2)=1]
```

Other solutions using different technologies are left as an exercise to the reader; this is just a brief, contrived example for illustration.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>If you specify a type or universal selector, it must come first. This does not change how selectors fundamentally work, however; it's nothing more than a syntactic quirk.</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>This was originally proposed as `:nth-match()`, however because it still counts an element relative only to its siblings, and not to every other element that matches the given selector, it has since as of 2014 been repurposed as an extension to the existing `:nth-child()` instead.</sub>

Comment: "(you'll notice my use of an unordered list here, just to drive the point home)" I wish more people were that deliberate about their use of ordered vs unordered bullets. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @The Red Pea: One of my biggest HTML pet peeves: "In order from highest/lowest to lowest/highest:" followed by an unordered list. I mean come on, seriously?

Comment: This is not a misunderstanding but rather a CSS feature request, see https://www.bram.us/2020/03/16/css-nth-of-class-selector/

Comment: @Ingo Steinke: The question was not phrased as a feature request. It was predicated on a misunderstanding of how :nth-child() works.

Answer (score 8):

Not really..

[quote from the docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#nth-child-pseudo)

> The `:nth-child` pseudo-class matches an
>   element that has an+b-1 **siblings
>   before it in the document tree**, for a
>   given positive or zero value for n,
>   and has a parent element.

It is a selector of its own and does not combine with classes. In your rule it just has to satisfy both selector at the same time, so it will show the `:nth-child(even)` table rows if they also happen to have the `.row` class.

Answer (score 2):

`nth-of-type` works according to the index of same type of the element but `nth-child` works only according to index no matter what type of siblings elements are.

**For example**

```
<div class="one">...</div>
<div class="two">...</div>
<div class="three">...</div>
<div class="four">...</div>
<div class="five">...</div>
<div class="rest">...</div>
<div class="rest">...</div>
<div class="rest">...</div>
<div class="rest">...</div>
<div class="rest">...</div>
```

Suppose in above html we want to hide all the elements having rest class.

In this case `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` will work exactly same as all the element are of same type that is `<div>` so css should be

```
.rest:nth-child(6), .rest:nth-child(7), .rest:nth-child(8), .rest:nth-child(9), .rest:nth-child(10){
    display:none;
}
```

**OR**

```
.rest:nth-of-type(6), .rest:nth-of-type(7), .rest:nth-of-type(8), .rest:nth-of-type(9), .rest:nth-of-type(10){
    display:none;
}
```

**Now you must be wondering what is the difference between `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` so this is the difference**

Suppose the html is

```
<div class="one">...</div>
<div class="two">...</div>
<div class="three">...</div>
<div class="four">...</div>
<div class="five">...</div>
<p class="rest">...</p>
<p class="rest">...</p>
<p class="rest">...</p>
<p class="rest">...</p>
<p class="rest">...</p>
```

In the above html the type of `.rest` element is different from others `.rest` are paragraphs and others are div so in this case if you use `nth-child` you have to write like this

```
.rest:nth-child(6), .rest:nth-child(7), .rest:nth-child(8), .rest:nth-child(9), .rest:nth-child(10){
    display:none;
}
```

**but if you use nth-of-type** css can be this

```
.rest:nth-of-type(1), .rest:nth-of-type(2), .rest:nth-of-type(3), .rest:nth-of-type(4), .rest:nth-of-type(5){
    display:none;
}
```

> As type of `.rest` element is `<p>` so here `nth-of-type` is detecting the type of `.rest` and then he applied css on the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th element of `<p>`.

Comment: How useful is that for `<tr>` tags?

Answer (score 2):

## 2023 answer: Now you can!

```css
table.myClass tr:nth-child(odd of .row) {}
```

Generalized version ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2022/WD-selectors-4-20221111/#the-nth-child-pseudo)):

```css
:nth-child(<nth> [of <selector>]?) {}
```

...in which `<nth>` is `2`, `3n + 1`, `-n + 3`, `odd` or [other valid values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#syntax) and `<selector>` is a list of selectors, which may be complex.

At the time of writing, this feature is only supported in Chrome 111+ (2023/03/07, also for Android), Firefox 113+ (2023/05/09, also for Android), Edge 111+ (2023/03/13) and Safari 9+ (2015/10/01, also for iOS), [according to caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/css-nth-child-of).

Try it:

```css
/*** First example ***/

/* All odds (2n + 1) */
#example-1 > :nth-child(odd of .foo) {
  background: red;
}

/* Odd evens (4n + 2) */
/* Note how .foo:not(...) is evaluated first */
#example-1 > :nth-child(odd of .foo:not(:nth-child(odd of .foo))) {
  background: yellow;
}

/*** Second example ***/

/* This works */
#example-2 > :nth-of-type(3) {
  background: red;
}

/* This too */
#example-2 > :nth-child(4 of div) {
  background: yellow;
}

/* And so will this */
#example-2 > :nth-last-child(11 of div) {
  background: green;
}

/* Use :nth-last-child() to select from last */
/* First 2 of last 3 of <div>s */
#example-2 > :nth-child(-n + 2 of :nth-last-child(-n + 3 of div)) {
  background: cyan;
}

/* 1st, 4th, 7th... from last */
#example-2 > :nth-last-child(3n + 1 of div) {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* ...of which odd elements will be selected */
#example-2 > :nth-last-child(odd of :nth-last-child(3n + 1)) {
  outline: 3px solid black;
}

/*** Other styles ***/

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(5, 1fr) / repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.flex > div,
.grid > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* 2nd, 3rd, 4th... of both .flex and .grid */
body > :nth-child(n + 2 of .flex, .grid) {
  gap: 10px;
}

/* First 1 of [2nd, 3rd, 4th...] <div>s */
body > :nth-child(-n + 1 of :nth-child(n + 2 of div)) > div {
  background: #ddd;
}

/* 2nd of last 2 of [1st, 2nd, 3rd...] non-<script> from last */
/* ...which means 1st from last */
:nth-child(odd of :nth-last-child(-n + 3 of body > :not(script))) > .foo {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
:nth-child(odd of :nth-last-child(-n + 3 of body > :not(script))) > .foo::after {
  content: '.foo';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex" id="example-1">
  <div>odd</div>
  <div>even</div>
  <div class="foo">1st odd</div>
  <div class="foo">1st even</div>
  <div class="foo">2nd odd</div>
  <div class="foo">2nd even</div>
  <div class="foo">3rd odd</div>
  <div class="foo">3rd even</div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="flex" id="example-2">
  <div>1 (15)</div>
  <div class="foo">2 (14)</div>
  <div>3 (13)</div>
  <div class="foo">4 (12)</div>
  <div>5 (11)</div>
  <div>6 (10)</div>
  <div class="foo">7 (9)</div>
  <div>8 (8)</div>
  <div>9 (7)</div>
  <div class="foo">10 (6)</div>
  <div class="foo">11 (5)</div>
  <div>12 (4)</div>
  <div class="foo">13 (3)</div>
  <div>14 (2)</div>
  <div>15 (1)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do that with xpath. something like `//tr[contains(@class, 'row') and position() mod 2 = 0]` might work. There are other SO questions expanding on the details how to match classes more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>TEST</title>

  <style>

    .block {
      background: #fc0;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    /* .large > .large-item:nth-of-type(n+5) {
      background: #f00;
    } */

    .large-item ~ .large-item ~ .large-item ~ .large-item ~ .large-item {
      background: #f00;
    }

  </style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Should be the 6th Hello Block that start red</h1>
<div class="small large">
  <div class="block small-item">Hello block 1</div>
  <div class="block small-item large-item">Hello block 2</div>
  <div class="block small-item large-item">Hello block 3</div>
  <div class="block small-item large-item">Hello block 4</div>
  <div class="block small-item large-item">Hello block 5</div>
  <div class="block small-item large-item">Hello block 6</div>
  <div class="block small-item large-item">Hello block 7</div>
  <div class="block small-item large-item">Hello block 8</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

All of the questions around using nth-child and skipping hidden tags appear to be redirecting as dupes of this one so I will leave this here. I came across this blog https://blog.blackbam.at/2015/04/09/css-nth-child-selector-ignore-hidden-element/ that uses a clever css approach to make nth-child ignore hidden elements, as follows:

The following CSS adds a margin right to every second visible element no matter which element has the cpw class.

```
.cpw {
    display:none;
}

.video_prewrap {
    margin-right:20px;
}

.video_prewrap:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right:0;
}

.cpw ~ .video_prewrap:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right:20px;
}

.cpw ~ .video_prewrap:nth-child(2n-1) {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Hope that helps someone who is following the dupe trail for the ignore hidden elements questions!

Comment: I'd like to upvote this but it needs a working demo.

Comment: My recollection is that this wasn't actually as robust as it seemed initially - I'd now go with the top voted comment, this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

IF you have same parent class for all selector, Then you use that class `document.querySelector("main .box-value:nth-child(3) select.priorityOption");`
Because in that case `document.querySelector("main .box-value select.priorityOption:nth-child(3)");` Not working. Thank You

```
<div class="card table">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-value">
            <select class="priorityOption">
                <option value="">--</option>
                <option value="">LOREM</option>
                <option value="">LOREM</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="box-value">
            <select class="priorityOption">
                <option value="">--</option>
                <option value="">LOREM</option>
                <option value="">LOREM</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="box-value">
            <select class="priorityOption">
                <option value="">--</option>
                <option value="">LOREM</option>
                <option value="">LOREM</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer to "Can someone explain why?" since other answers has explained.

But as one possible solution to your situation, you may use custom tags for the rows and cells, say `<tr-row>`, `<td-row>`, then `:nth-of-type()` should work. Don't forget to set style `display: table-row;` and `display: table-cell;` respectively to make them still work like table cells.