# Combining :last-child with :not(.class) selector in CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to choose the last child that does NOT have a class attr?
Like such:

```
<tr> ... </tr>
<tr> ... </tr>
<tr> ... </tr>
<tr class="table_vert_controls"> ... </tr>
```

I want to select the third row, in this case.

I tried the following, which did not work:

```
tr:not(.table_vert_controls):last-child
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is what you are expecting. Refer **BoltClock** answer **[CSS3 :nth-child(odd) with a selector](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5546296/500725)**

Comment: Thanks for the hint Siva! That wasn't exactly what i needed, but i ended up using nth-last-child. Since the row with the class always comes last, i used nth-last-child to select the row i needed.

Comment: @dcastro: As in `tr:nth-last-child(2)`? That works too :)

Comment: @BoltClock yes, that's what i used! ^^

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Not with CSS selectors alone, no, as `:last-child` specifically looks at *the last child*, and there isn't a similar `:last-of-class` pseudo-class. See my answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector/5546296#5546296).

As of late 2015, implementations have begun slowly trickling in for Selectors 4's extension to `:nth-child()` and `:nth-last-child()` which allow you to pass an arbitrary selector as an argument (more on that also in an update to the linked answer). You will then be able to write the following:

```
tr:nth-last-child(1 of :not(.table_vert_controls))
```

Although implementations have recently begun to ship, it will still take at least a few more years for this to be widely supported (as of April 2018, two and a half years after being the first browser to ship, [Safari remains the only browser to have done so](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Browser_compatibility)). In the meantime, you'll have to use something else, like an extra class just before the class in question, or a jQuery selector:

```
$('tr:not(.table_vert_controls):last')
```

Comment: @Tomalak: No, as `:last-of-type` doesn't have a functional notation, and only looks at the element type (in this case, `tr`).

Comment: Thanks. I've already deleted it. (You jQuery code was the first version of my answer, until I noticed that this is not about jQuery in the first place...)

Comment: Be aware that `:first-child` and `:last-child` will match white space between elements.

Comment: @rxgx: No, they won't. Are you confusing the selectors with the `firstChild` and `lastChild` DOM properties?

Answer (score 0):

my case was to find the last th\td without class "hidden-cell" inside the tr
only this code works for me

```css
        tr {
          td:nth-last-child(-n + 1 of td:not(.hidden-cell)),
          th:nth-last-child(-n + 1 of th:not(.hidden-cell)) {
            /** any style you need */
            background-color: red !important;
            border-width: 20px !important;
            max-width: 20px !important;
            width: 20px !important;
            min-width: 20px !important;
          }
        }
```

in you case lets say

```css
   tbody {
          tr:nth-last-child(-n + 1 of tr:not(.table_vert_controls)){
            /** any style you need */
            background-color: red !important;
            border-width: 20px !important;
            max-width: 20px !important;
            width: 20px !important;
            min-width: 20px !important;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the following solution:

```
tr:not(.table_vert_controls):nth-last-of-type(2)
```