# CSS selector to get the last visible element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, less

I have a list of buttons where the first and last *visible* buttons should have special styling (eg, rounded corners.) The catch is some buttons are hidden, so I can't simply use the `:last-child` pseudo class.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a class="btn hide">one</a>
    <a class="btn">two</a>
    <a class="btn">three</a>
    <a class="btn">four</a>
    <a class="btn hide">five</a>
</div>
```

And the CSS (using LESS) selector that doesn't work:

```
.btn:not(.hide):first-child {
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.btn:not(.hide):last-child {
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}
```

The end goal is to apply special styling to the second and fourth buttons. Also, **this only needs to work in Chrome.** I know this can be done with jQuery selectors, but I'd rather handle this in my style sheet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300185/combining-last-child-with-not-class-selector-in-css

Comment: Have you had a look at `nth-child` ? So for example `a:nth-child(4) {color:red; }`

Comment: You could always just do `.btn:nth-child(3);`

Comment: That wouldn't work since the same buttons aren't always visible, they'll change as the user performs certain actions.

Comment: @Zenith this question might be a duplicate then, unless something has changed since that question was answered (which was more than a year ago.)

Comment: @theabraham Sadly, until CSS4 comes around, I don't think anything will change :/

Comment: @theabraham: Yeah, no it hasn't changed :/ (Source: I answered that other question)

Comment: I thought that probably something like this would help you: div > .btn:not(.hide):first-of-type{} but this does not works..this works:div > a:last-of-type{} ...I do not know why..here is a jfiddle showing this behaviour http://jsfiddle.net/h2Tez/

Comment: @sandino that doesn't solve the problem :/, but thanks for trying. I'll bite the bullet and use jQuery selectors.

Comment: yes I know, or if you want not to use jquery (for some reason) generate a distinct class name for the first and last elements (a) of the type you want to give some special css