# Change DIV width that is before another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this structure with dynamic DIVs and all have the same class, since all are created automatically.

The problem here is that, the last of them prior to other DIV with other class, I would like to have his style as width:100% instead of width:50% as all others set by CSS.

Here's a sample:

```
<div class="awp_box awp_box_inner"></div>
<div class="awp_box awp_box_inner"></div>
<div class="awp_box awp_box_inner"></div>
<div class="awp_stock_container awp_sct" style="max-width: 400px !important;"></div>
```

So I only want to change that third DIV, which sometimes is the first and only one, other times is the second, other times is the fourth, etc...

I am usually good with CSS but this time I'm having a hard time finding a solution for this one.

Can someone please give me a hand here guiding me in the right track so I could put this working?

Comment: so what you want is to have the last occurrence of .awp_box awp_box_inner to have width:100% correct?

Comment: add a class to the box you wish to style as width:100% , static CSS can't give you what you need.

Comment: @Math3w since code is dynamic, I can't just rename the last DIV of those first three because those are creatd dynamicaly. Thank you anyway.

Comment: does the box you want to style have any unique attribute with it? using jquery to find that unique attr and addClass.

Comment: Indeed, it has many other DIVs inside with specific classes and also an input button inside also with specific class name. Your idea could actually be a good one, but... "jquery is not my friend" (I don't know codding jquery). :P

Comment: @Pedro so do you want to change the last one or the one before last?

Comment: @sdcr I want to change always the one before the last DIV with class="awp_stock_container awp_sct".

Comment: @sdcr maybe I couldn't explain myself clearly, but those three DIVs with same class are dynamic in my website. Sometimes it's only 1, othertimes are 5 or 4... what I want is to change always the last one (that is always before DIV with class="awp_stock_container awp_sct"). So I don't want to change that last one in my example but, instead, I want to change the third one in my example (keep in mind that it's automatically generated).

Comment: @Pedro maybe it's not possible to do fyi - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300185/combining-last-child-with-not-class-selector-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the following script could give you what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.awp_sct').prev().addClass('full');
});
```

It will add a class to the previous element of the .awp_sct.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Math3w_C/sjf033xs/)**

Comment: And this is why I love stackoverflow! :D
Thank you SO much for taking your time to help me. I was actually getting there as well with this solution: $('.awp_box.awp_box_inner').last().css('width', '100%');
Anyway, I have chosen to implement yours. :)

Answer (score 2):

If I was correct in my question above then add this CSS

```
div.awp_box.awp_box_inner:nth-last-child(1) {
     width: 100%;
}
```

Source: [TutsPlus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048)

Comment: First let me thank you for your answer. Yes, that is what I want but unfortunately it didn't worked. :(