# CSS Get last-child that doesn't have a class

Tags: css

Here is a tricky challenge for you guys, CSS selector to get the `:last-child` that doesn't have a class.

What I have tried so far:

```
.nav-item:not(.nav-item--mobile):last-child {...}
.nav-item:last-child:not(.nav-item--mobile) {...}
```

I have similar query selectors that do some fun stuff, so I'd rather try and do this via CSS. The mobile items can be variable in quantity.

```
// Get the first child in the list when there are n or more, and
// they are not mobile. Yes, this actually works.
.nav-item:first-child:nth-last-child(n+7):not(.nav-item--mobile)
```

The following will give me the last child in all cases, but I want the last child that isn't a mobile only child.

```
.navigation-item--top:last-child
```

#### Target

```
generic generic generic generic generic mobile mobile
                                   ^
                             target this one
```

#### HTML

```
<ul class="nav-items-list">
    <li class="nav-item"></li>
    <li class="nav-item"></li>
    <li class="nav-item"></li>
    <li class="nav-item"></li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-item--mobile"></li>
    <li class="nav-item nav-item--mobile"></li>
</ul>
```

*Yes I could figure out which is the correct one in the generated navigation, or I could find it with JS.*

Comment: Can you post your HTML structure too please.

Comment: `:last-child` asks **only one question**, no matter what else you specify: **Am I the last child of my parent element?**

Comment: @connexo I thought so, but I was hoping that wasn't the case. I was hoping it was kinda contextual on the selector.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It is not even planned for selectors level 4. https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-last-child-pseudo

Comment: Possible dupilcate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300185/combining-last-child-with-not-class-selector-in-css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately what you want cannot be achieved using CSS only.

`:last-child` asks **only one question**, no matter what else you specify: **Am I the last child of my parent element?**

Sadly, there is no `:last-of-class`, only `:last-of-type`, but this cares only about element type.

It is not even planned for selectors level 4 that you can specifiy a class or other limiting property. 
See

> https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-last-child-pseudo

Comment: That's fine dude, thanks for the answer. I have a workaround that is much less fun. Marked as correct.