# CSS/JS selector - Select last element where class is not equal to

Tags: javascript, css, select, element

I am trying to get from a HTML table the `latest` **td** tag from the `latest` **tr** where the latest td-tag should `not` have the class **disabled**.

Im doing this in pure JavaScript using CSS selectors (no jQuery please!). I tried a few possibilities but all returning null or "invalid selector" message. Also the solution posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8300185/combining-last-child-with-not-class-selector-in-css) is not working for me.

Some of my attempts:

```
var table = document.getElementById('example');
var test1 = table.querySelector('tr:last-child > td:nth-last-child(:not(.disabled))');
var test2 = table.querySelector('tr:last-child > td:nth-last-child:not(.disabled)');
var test3 = table.querySelector('tr:last-child > td:nth-last-child(1 of :not(.disabled))');
var test4 = table.querySelector('tr:last-child > td:not(.disabled):last-child');
```

For example:

```
<table id="example">
    <tr>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td class="disabled"> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="disabled"> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> Value I want </td>
        <td class="disabled"> ... </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In here I need the value `Value I want`, but I'm not able to get it. Does someone knows whats wrong?

Comment: Clear description of problem? Check. Data to replicate the problem provided? Check. Clear attempt at solving the problem before posting? Check. A well-asked question.

Comment: Don't know what's wrong about my question tho... it's short but straight to the point

Comment: Sorry, I may have been unclear. "Well-asked question" meaning "A good question, asked properly." At least in my view, there isn't anything wrong with it. (When I saw that comment I worried people had downvoted, but that doesn't seem to be the case.) I mentioned it out of appreciation: Well-asked questions are all too rare on SO, particularly in the CSS and JS tags. Nice one!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I understand it now. Again thanks for the asnwer, it's working fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS doesn't have a "last" pseudoclass, and `:last-child` and `:last-of-type` are not applicable to what you want.

Since you seem to want to select the element with JavaScript, though, it's simple: Select all `td` that don't have `.disabled` and take the last one:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("td:not(.disabled)");
var last = list[list.length - 1];
```

Or scoped to that table:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#example td:not(.disabled)");
var last = list[list.length - 1];
```

Example:

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#example td:not(.disabled)");
var last = list[list.length - 1];
console.log(last.innerHTML);
```

```html
<table id="example">
    <tr>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td class="disabled"> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="disabled"> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> ... </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> ... </td>
        <td> Value I want </td>
        <td class="disabled"> ... </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Weird that it can't be archieved which CSS selectors only. Anyway, thanks for the (quick) answer, this will do indeed the job!