# nth-last-child or :last-of-type with a selector

Tags: html, css

I have a table that sometimes have a special row, sometime doesn't :

```
<td>normal</td>
<td>normal</td>
<td>normal</td>
<td>normal</td>
<td class="_SPECIAL_">special</td>
```

I want to apply a style to the first and last td, but the last td *MUST* exlude the `_SPECIAL_` row.

so I am trying to to

```
      td {
        // style

        &:first-child {
          // style
        }

        &:last-child:not(._SPECIAL_) {
          // style
        }
```

It doesn't apply the style to the special, but I don7t know how to apply to the one previous.

I am also trying with `nth-last-child` or `last-of-type` but same problem. Is there a trick or is it impossible ?

EDIT :

Basically, the following snippet is **VERY** simplified (so please no solution that would solve only the snippet...), I would like to find a css that would allow me for all the table in my app to.

- Style first td of each row
- Style last td of each row (and if last td is of class `_SPECIAL_` style the previous td instead.)

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

td:first-child {
 background-color:red;
}

td:last-child {
 background-color:green;
}
```

```html
 THIS IS OK 
<br/>
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
HERE I WANT THE ROW COUNTRY COLORED BUT NOT THE ROW SPECIAL
<br/>
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Special</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td class="_SPECIAL">Special</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example  in your question

Comment: @danhuong done.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think there is a pure CSS solution to this problem yet. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8300258/4157513. You may need to use Javascript/JQuery.

Comment: I'm the author of the answer @wahoowa linked to. Before we make a conclusion, Bobby, can I ask if there isn't a special td, will there always be only three tds, and if there is one, will there always be four? Also, when there's a Special column, what styles should apply if a row *doesn't* have a special td? Or is that something that will never occur in your code? I understand the snippet is simplified but I still wanted to try and narrow things down.

Comment: @BoltClock Hi, thanks for the reply. So there is no fix amount of td. for the explanation, I am making an angular app, and I have different table trought the app, some have a special row (with a button) that in normal view will be displayed on the side. 

https://i.imgur.com/dcMCUkB.png

Some do not have that row.

https://i.imgur.com/2fAfDd6.png

Comment: To respect the design guideline, * I need the first td to have a padding top of let s say 16
* the td in the middle to have padding top/bot of 8px * the last td to have a padding bottom of 16px;

Comment: Problem is, on mobile, when the table have the speciale special row that goes on the side (on purpose with some css positioning) the padding bottom  should be applied to the td just before it or the layout will not work correctly. If there is no Special row, just on the last child is ok.

Comment: So I am trying to find a way to apply a padding to the last child (if not special), or previous child of last child (if last is special) so that the padding bottom will always be applied to the correct element and do not break the layout visually

Comment: I do not need IE etc compatibility, so I am tryin to play with some css 4 selector that works on chrome/firefox. but no change yet.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, the level 4 solution isn't supported by any other browser besides Safari yet. Very frustrating. I think the duplicate link does apply in this case, you'll need to add a class. Sorry I can't be of more help but thanks for providing the context!

Comment: sad ^^ ok thank you !

Answer (score 0):

idk this solution actually resolve your problem but i try with `:not()` first and `last-child` next and it works

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

td:first-child {
 background-color:red;
}

td:last-child {
 background-color:green;
}
td:not(._SPECIAL):last-child {
 background-color:orange;

}
```

```html
THIS IS OK 
<br/>
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br/>
<br/>
HERE I WANT THE ROW COUNTRY COLORED BUT NOT THE ROW SPECIAL
<br/>
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Special</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td class="_SPECIAL">Special</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The OP wants the second to last `<td>` to be styled if the `td:last-child` of a row contains the `_SPECIAL_` class.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the thing is, the last td, or td before the special should have the same styles. so in the Exemples Germany should have the same style in both table. so this do not really solve ^^