# css first child doesn't work on my <li>

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

CSS

```
.list-group-item:first-child{
  border-top: none !important;
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in data">
 {{user.name}}
</li>
```

What's wrong with my first-child?

demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/FKXdsJRc9eu4TiN9UPMY?p=preview

Comment: everything seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/7Aa4x/

Comment: @web-tiki: it fails: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/7Aa4x/3/

Comment: See [(this)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/1355315) and [(this)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5546296/1355315) for more info

Comment: @abhitalks well in OP example, the first li has that class so it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change it in two ways:

A) Use it on the li (as now) but use first-of-type

B) Nest the li's in an ul class="example" (which you are supposed to do) and do

```
.example:first-child{
    border-top: none !important;
}
```

(Your example edited: http://plnkr.co/edit/QTlaDQPXfdg3W6oNYex4?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

The `:first-child` selector is intended, to select the first child of a parent `tag`. The children have to be embedded in the same parent tag, it is not to be used with `css class`.

If you want to select first list item, you chould modify it to select first child of `<ul>` tag.

```
li:first-child{
  border-top: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Embed the list in `<ul></ul>` tags, as they are expected to, and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `!important` from list-group-item class `border-top`

CSS:

```
.list-group-item {
padding: 6px 15px !important;
border-top: 2px solid #DDD;
padding-top: 15px !important;
}
```

HTML:

something here

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-group-item ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="user in data">jason</li>
    <li class="list-group-item ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="user in data">james</li>
    <li class="list-group-item ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="user in data">josh</li>
    <li class="list-group-item ng-scope ng-binding" ng-repeat="user in data">joshua</li>
</ul>
```

**[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/QC37e/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

http://plnkr.co/edit/jqecyBMcrLfVaGtxhIaM?p=preview

```
 <ul><li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="user in data">
{{user.name}}
</li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any parent tag there. You should use something like this:

HTML

```
<ul class="list-group-item">
  <li ng-repeat="user in data">
    {{user.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.list-group-item li {
  padding: 6px 15px !important;
  border-top: 2px solid #DDD !important;
  padding-top: 15px !important;
}

.list-group-item li:first-child {
  border-top: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`<ul class="First">
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
 <li></li>
</ul>`

If you have this kind of structure you can access the first child by giving style like this :

.First li:first-child {

/*your style comes here*/

}

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve the answer in different way, Not Sure why first:child is not working

```
.list-group-item {
  padding: 6px 15px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #DDD;
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.list-group-item:last-child{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}
```