# Select :first-child or :last-child that doesn't contain some specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Assume we're having a list with 5 items and we want to apply some **specific styles** to the first or the last child. But the functionality of this list will require to hide some of its items by applying through jQuery a class (let's call it `.hide`) which will set a `display: none;` on the targeted items.

The **specific styles** I was talking at the beginning should be only applied to the FIRST and the LAST items that are visible, so what I'm trying to achieve is to somehow skip the ones which have the `.hide` class applied on them and are in the same time the first or the last items.

I already tried to do this by combining some `:not(.hide)` and `:first-child`/`:last-child` pseudos, but it doesn't work. Also, trying to use simbling selectors will work at most for the first child, but there's no way right now to select a previous sibling in css so this solution will not cover the last child problem.

Here's a jsfidle where you can better understand what I'm trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/3wgxt1oL/

or

**HTML**

```
<div class="hide">Item 1</div>
<div>Item 2</div>
<div>Item 3</div>
<div>Item 4</div>
<div class="hide">Item 5</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide {display: none;}
div:not(.hide):first-child,
div:not(.hide):last-child {color: red;}
```

Comment: please always insert the code also on the question. If jsfiddle goes down the question lose its meaning

Comment: Are you using javascript? you didn't tag any JS

Comment: You could use `.detach` instead of `.hide`

Comment: Not possible with CSS selectors. These pseudo-class sectors use **elements** not classes and properties. A JS solution would be required.

Comment: CSS
 can't select a child after deselecting a particular class. Chaining is not possible in CSS!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, this is not possible with CSS selectors. The reason is twofold:

- `:first-child` and `:last-child` represent the first and last children of their parents, period. They do not represent the first and last child elements matching the rest of the selector. Chaining `:not(.hide)` simply tells the selector to ignore the element if it has the `.hide` class; it does not change the meaning of the rest of the selector.
- [There is currently no other pseudo-class available for the first or last (or nth) element matching an arbitrary selector.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-childodd-with-a-selector)

Since you're already using jQuery to apply the `.hide` class, you can use it to apply another class to the first and last elements matching `:not(.hide)`, then target those additional classes in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var notHidden = $('div').not('.hide');
notHidden.first().css('color', 'red');
notHidden.last().css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: Yes, something like this. What I forgot to mention is that I was wondering if this can be accomplished only by CSS. I was hoping there's a chance to use that `:not` selector somehow else to make it work.

Comment: But then how does CSS know which element is the first or the last?

Comment: can you please elaborate on this? what is that code there? This answer could be useful if it contained more information for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can add specific style to first visible child, like this:

```
.hide {display: none;}
div:not(.hide){
  color: red;
}
div:not(.hide) ~ div:not(.hide){
    color: black; /*reset everything to normal*/
}
```

But there is no way select last visible child with css. For this you need  use javascript