# css nested only-of-type selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So i have this situation:

```
<div class="wrapper"> 
     <div class="optional">
         <h3>one</h3>
         <textarea/>
     </div>
     <div class="optional">
         <h3>one</h3>
         <textarea/>
     </div> 
</div>
```

inside `wrapper` there are more elements.
Sometimes I have 1 `optional` and other times more than once.
I want to add different

```
.optional{textarea{ height: 150px;  }} 
.optional:only-of-type{textarea{ height: 75px;  }} //sass
```

but sadly this is not working (I know.. only on elements, not classes).

So - is there a way without JS to give a different height to the `textarea` when there is only one?

Comment: Actually, it seems to be working.  Can you confirm? http://jsfiddle.net/suu45uod/

Comment: @JosephMarikle You are right! but still my code not working... So weird. so look at my real code: http://jsfiddle.net/suu45uod/2/

Comment: @Joseph Marikle: Your fiddle does not account for the fact that there may be more non-optional elements in the wrapper as the OP has stated (and implied by stating that the selector only looks at elements, not classes).

Comment: @BoltClock I realized that after looking back at it again.  This is a better example: http://jsfiddle.net/jmarikle/suu45uod/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have my solution now - 
Instead of `div.optional` I Just chose an other **rare** element (`section`), and then I can select `only-of-type` again. 
Simple but ugly :)

Answer (score 2):

As you have stated, `:only-of-type` doesn't scope itself to classes.

Since [CSS doesn't yet provide an analogue of `*-of-type` for arbitrary selector sub-matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-child-with-a-class-selector), and additionally CSS does not provide a way to determine if an element is the only *grandchild* of its type (or the only grandchild, period), you will have to do this with JS.

Comment: Just hoped there will be a nice hack somehow. Back to JS. thanks. BTW - Why does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/suu45uod) works and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/suu45uod/4/) not?

Comment: @yonatanmn: There is an additional `<div data-reactid=".0.2.0.$=10:0.1.$=10:0.8">` without the class that is a sibling of your other divs.

Comment: @yonatanmn: That div is the only child of its own parent wrapper, so by necessity it is also the only one of its type.