# A CSS selector or xpath to iterate over rows with specific attributes

Tags: html, xpath, css-selectors

Imagine I am given a table like this:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#">B</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#">C</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>D</td></tr>
  <tr><td><a href="#">E</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td>B</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to construct a CSS selector (preferred) or an XPath (accepted) that picks out the n'th row that contains an `a` anchor, such that:

```
selector(1) => <a href="#">B</a>
selector(2) => <a href="#">C</a>
selector(3) => <a href="#">E</a>
```

#### CSS selectors

At this point, I'm pretty sure that CSS won't do the job, but

```
'table tr:nth-child(' + n + ')'
```

will pick out the n'th row, but that selects rows whether or not they have an `a` anchor.  Similarly,

```
'table tr:nth-child(' + n + ') a'
```

will pick out rows with an `a` anchor, but only if `n` is 2, 3 or 5.

#### XPath

With XPath, this matches all the `tr` that have an `a`

```
`//table//tr//a/ancestor::tr`
```

but I can't figure out how to select the n'th match.  In particular,

```
`//table//tr//a/ancestor::tr[position() = 2]`
```

doesn't appear to select anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with a CSS selector<sup>1</sup> for a number of reasons:

- [There is no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), and
- [There is no selector for matching the nth child satisfying an arbitrary selector.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-a-class-selector)

Your XPath is incorrect because `a/ancestor::tr[position() = 2]` returns the second `tr` ancestor of the `a` element. That is, the `[position() = 2]` predicate is connected to the `ancestor::` axis. This XPath would match the middle-level `tr` in the following HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr><td><table>
    <tr><td><table>
      <tr><td><a href="#"></a>
    </table>
  </table>
</table>
```

In your HTML, each `a` element has only one `tr` ancestor, so this will not select anything.

The XPath you should use is:

```
(//table//tr[descendant::a])[2]
```

This matches the second `tr` element that contains an `a` descendant.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>In Selectors 4, a potential solution would be `table tr:nth-match(2 of :has(a))`.</sub>

Comment: Bingo.  Good explanation as well.  Strictly speaking I suppose the real answer is `(//table//tr[descendant::a])[2]//a` to pick out the `a` elements.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can find the nth `td` which has an `<a href` like so (you want `C` to be the 2nd match?):

```
(/table//tr/td[a[@href]])[2]
```

If you can't guarantee a td element, you can wild card the path and elements:

```
(/table//tr//*[a[@href]])[2]
```

Comment: Ah!  This works as well.  I didn't previously know that you could use parentheses in XPath for -- essentially -- operator precedence.  This approach feels more straightforward than using descendant::

Comment: I guess one thing to point out is that [// is short for /descendant-or-self::node()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/). :)

Answer (score 0):

Answers from @BoltClock and @StuartLC both work.  But now that I know parentheses in XPath can control operator precedence, a more straightforward solution seems to be:

```
(//table//tr//a)[2]
```

Am I missing something?