# nth-child skipping over specific class less

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I need to select the nth child of a class not counting elements of a specific class in less. As an example, given:

li
li class="skip_this"
li
li
li

I want to make the nth-child skip the skip_this class when counting, meaning that if I wanted the 3rd li that is not skip_this, it would actually select the 4th li, because it wouldn't count the one with skip_this.

Comment: If the answer did not work or you meant something else let me know so I can help

Comment: No, this can't be done with LESS and/or CSS ... whenever you use `:nth-of-type` or `:nth-child` as demonstrated below, the nth selector applies to the HTML elements as children of their parent and counts them as such; so item number 2 will always be item number 2, whereas you want the "counter" to skip the second list item in your example and count the 3rd list item as the 2nd item not to have the "skip_this" class ... you'll have to do this with scripting, not CSS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS3 :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with a class selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-a-class-selector)

Answer (score 4):

Use [**:not()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) like

```
li:nth-child(2n):not(.skip_class){

}
```

```css
li:nth-child(2n):not(.skip_class){
    background:green;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
 
   <li>test</li>
   <li class="skip_class">test</li>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
   <li>test</li>
  </ul>
```

**Update**

> My intention is that if I wanted to select the 2nd child that is not 'skip_class', it would select the third child, since the 2nd child is a 'skip_class'

Use the immediate sibling selector `+` like

```
li:nth-child(2n):not(.skip_class), .skip_class + :not(.skip_class)
```

```css
li:nth-child(2n):not(.skip_class),
.skip_class +:not(.skip_class) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>test</li>
  <li class="skip_class">test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

**Udpate**

To make it clear, trying to target a set of elements with a condition (class) irrespective of some siblings does not work because `nth-child` and `nth-of-type` will target **all** siblings or siblings of the same type.

When you add a condition(`:not(.skip_class)`), it works **independently** of the the other selector(`nth-child`)

See [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-a-class-selector)

Comment: why the `odd` selector?

Comment: @salniro, its just an example. It will work with any nth-child selector. I can change it if you like

Comment: oh it's no biggie I thought I perhaps didn't understand OP's question. `:not(.skip_class)` should suffice but the extra example shouldn't hurt

Comment: @salniro, changed it to use 2n instead

Comment: This doesn't work the way I was hoping for. It still counts the element in 'skip_class', it just doesn't run the code on it. My intention is that if I wanted to select the 2nd child that is not 'skip_class', it would select the third child, since the 2nd child is a 'skip_class'. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Yes it does but what your trying to do may not be possible in css because there are no 'look-behind' selectors. Can you put up a fiddle/HTML code to give me a clearer idea of your overall end goal? Btw, it is not possible in css. Less, I dont know

Comment: @OfekGila, a work around can be to use `.skip_class + :not(.skip_class)` like in https://jsfiddle.net/15f6dy9c/ . Does this work?

Comment: Thanks a bunch Ammar, but it still has a flaw. If I want to select the third element that is not .skip_class, it will select the third element in total, when I want to to select the 4th element in total because it shouldn't even count .skip_class

Comment: @OfekGila, I couldnt understand the last comment. What nth-child selector are you using? Can you provide a http://www.jsfiddle.net to make it more clear what your goals are?

Comment: Here: https://jsfiddle.net/15f6dy9c/2/
I want it to highlight the 4th element, because it shouldn't have even counted the 2nd one.

Comment: @OfekGila, it would not have counted the second one anyways https://jsfiddle.net/15f6dy9c/3/

Comment: @AmmarCSE, perhaps this example is better: https://jsfiddle.net/15f6dy9c/5/

Thanks a bunch btw

Comment: @OfekGila, no problem. Im just trying to understand what you want. For examle, this one highlights the fourth element https://jsfiddle.net/15f6dy9c/7/ but im sure you mean something else. What do you mean? :)

Comment: @AmmarCSE, What I want exactly is to be able to highlight every nth element, ignoring those with 'skip_class' as though they do no exist. The context behind this is that imagine that those with skip_class are hidden from view, and thus I don't want to include them in the counting.

Comment: @OfekGila, I see what you want now and Im trying to work a solution. Just a question, can you use javascript/jquery?

Comment: Yes, in fact I came up with a solution that works in javascript and jquery, but my boss would much prefer to have one line in css that just works, and he thinks it should be possible.

Comment: @OfekGila, I think you should tell him it is not :). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-a-class-selector

Comment: @OfekGila, if they are hidden, why not change the hidden li element to another type of element? I mean, its hidden anyways

Comment: @AmmarCSE, that's basically what I did except a bit more complicated because it involved sortables. The thing is that n should change with the screen width so oh well. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Well, with a preprocessor it *is* possible to craft a "function" that can generate weird and bloating list of selectors (for a non-infinite count of elements) that effectively behaves like `:nth-child` skipping a specified items.
But the resulting CSS would be really incredibly bloated (basically it's just "counted"

```
li:not(.skip) 
    ~ li:not(.skip) 
        ~ li:not(.skip) 
            ~ li:not(.skip)
                ...
                    ~ li:not(.skip) {}
```

selector chain), so I don't think this actually could be a practical solution.

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/zGEwJy?editors=110)

The code in the demo generates the whole list at once (I think it's just a bit more easy to understand it this way), but the same method could be used to generate individual "skipping nth" items.

```js
/*
    "Please hack me to support Less" kernel. 
    
    Created by @aaronlayton
    Modified by meri
    Updated by max
*/

// Step 1: Select the style element and change it to text/less
$('head style').attr('type', 'text/less');

// Step 2: Set development mode to see errors
less.env = 'development';

// Step 3: Tell Less to refresh the styles
less.refreshStyles();
```

```css
@colors:
    #E74C3C
    #C0392B
    // #E67E22
    // #D35400
    #F1C40F
    #F39C12
    #2ECC71
    #27AE60
    // #1ABC9C
    // #16A085
    #3498DB
    #2980B9
    #9B59B6
    #8E44AD
    #34495E
    #2C3E50;

.make-rainbow(@colors, skipme);

li {
    padding: .5em;
    width:    2em;
    &:after {margin-left: 2em}
}

// ..................................
// impl:

.make-rainbow(@colors, @skip-class) {
    @next: ~;
    @n: length(@colors);
    .-; .-(@i: 1) {
        li:not(.@{skip-class}) {
            background-color: extract(@colors, @i);
            &:after {content: "@{i}"};
            @{next} when (@i < @n) {
                .-(@i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li class="skipme">skip</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li class="skipme">skip</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li class="skipme">skip</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/2.5.1/less.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but both the amount of items in the list will change with time, and n will change with time, and I think a javascript solution is the only way for me to go.