# Targeting the last element among a set of element types with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've tried this;

```
@mixin text-format{
>p, >ul, >h1, >h2, >h3, >h4, >h5{
    &:last-of-type{
        background-color:green;
    }
}
}

.text-body{
@include text-format;
}
```

Pure CSS

```
.text-body > p:last-of-type, .text-body > ul:last-of-type, .text-body > h1:last-of-type, .text-body > h2:last-of-type, .text-body > h3:last-of-type, .text-body > h4:last-of-type, .text-body > h5:last-of-type {
  background-color: green;
}
```

This selects the last instance of each of those element types, but exclusive to that element type. I simply want to select the last element within the div no matter what it is, but within the specified element types in the selector.

Fiddle;
http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/bcLt62jx/

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you might be looking for

```
.text-body > :nth-last-child(1 of p, ul, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5)
```

from [Selectors 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-last-child-pseudo) (originally specced as [`:nth-last-match()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#the-nth-last-match-pseudo)). This restricts the list of potential matches to just those element types, and picks the last occurrence of them within the parent element, `.text-body`. An illustration:

```
<div class="text-body">
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <ul></ul>
  <h2></h2>
  <p></p>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

In this example, there are six children, five of which are any of `p, ul, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5`. The last element out of these five is the `p` that immediately precedes the `span`, so it matches the above selector. The `h1` will match the equivalent `:nth-child()` expression, while the `span` will never match any such expression given the selector-list — in fact, the `span` itself can be expressed as `:not(p, ul, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5)`.

While `:nth-child()`, `:nth-last-child()` and `:not()` were all introduced in Selectors 3, the selector-list argument is new to Selectors 4. But no one has implemented it yet, and no one knows when it will be. Unfortunately, there is no equivalent using what is currently available, as it's *basically* the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-a-class-selector) except rather than a class selector, you're looking for the nth (last) child matching a *pool* of options. In both situations, you're dealing with the nth occurrence of some subset of an element's children.

Your best bet is to use JavaScript to, for example, add a class to the last instance among these element types on page load. Something like this with the native DOM/Selectors APIs:

```
var types = document.querySelectorAll('.text-body > p, .text-body > ul, .text-body > h1, .text-body > h2, .text-body > h3, .text-body > h4, .text-body > h5');
types[types.length - 1].className += ' last';
```

... which is quite the abomination compared to the following jQuery:

```
$('.text-body').children('p, ul, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5').last().addClass('last');
```

---

Note that

```
:nth-last-child(1 of p, ul, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5)
```

is *not* equivalent to

```
:last-child:matches(p, ul, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5)
```

as the latter matches the last child of its parent if and only if it is any one of those element types. In other words, `:last-child:matches(...)` is the Selectors 4 equivalent of `p, ul... { &:last-child { ... } }` (the second part of Harry's answer).

Answer (score 4):

If you need to select the last child within a parent element irrespective of it's element type then you need to use a simple `:last-child` selector like below:

```
& > :last-child{
  background-color:green;
}
```

The above selector will select the `last-child` within the `.text-body` irrespective of what type of element it is.

In the below snippet, you can see how the `background-color: green` is applied to the `last-child` of the both `.text-body` blocks even though the `last-child` within the first block is a `p` and that within the second block is a `span`.

```css
.text-body p,
.text-body ul {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.text-body >:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-body">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>
    But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
    happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful.
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <p>
    Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever
    undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant
    pleasure?
  </p>
</div>

<div class="text-body">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>
    But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
    happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful.
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <span>
    Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever
    undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant
    pleasure?
  </span>
</div>
```

---

On the other hand, if you want to select the last child only when its element type is one among a list of values then you need to use the `last-child` selector with an extra criteria like below:

```
>p, >ul, >h1, >h2, >h3, >h4, >h5{
    &:last-child{
        background-color:green;
    }
}
```

The above selector will select the `last-child` when its element type is one among `p`, `ul`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`.

If the element type of the `last-child` is anything other than these then the combination criteria would not be matched and hence the style would not get applied. In the below snippet, you can see how the `background-color: green` is applied to the `last-child` of the first `.text-body` but not to that of the second `.text-body` because in the 2nd, the last child is a `span`.

```css
.text-body p,
.text-body ul {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.text-body > p:last-child,
.text-body > ul:last-child,
.text-body > h1:last-child,
.text-body > h2:last-child,
.text-body > h3:last-child,
.text-body > h4:last-child,
.text-body > h5:last-child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-body">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>
    But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
    happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful.
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <p>
    Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever
    undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant
    pleasure?
  </p>
</div>

<div class="text-body">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>
    But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human
    happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful.
  </p>
  <ul>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
    <li>List item 4</li>
  </ul>
  <h2>Subtitle</h2>
  <span>
    Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever
    undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant
    pleasure?
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Harry, that works.

The issue now, is if I add a different type of element to the end, outside of those specified in the selector, the rule stops working.

Comment: @bazzlebrush: But that I thought that's what you meant by *but within the specified element types in the selector*. Or did you mean that you want to select the last-child within `.text-div` irrespective of the element type?

Comment: What I want is this;
Select the last instance of one of the types of elements listed in the selector.
This works but when you add another element at the end, which is not one of those listed in the selector, the rule stops working. You can see that happening here;
http://jsfiddle.net/bazzle/bcLt62jx/2/
Your first solution did 90% of what I'm looking for though, so thanks.

Comment: @bazzlebrush: I can't figure out any pure CSS selector. I know the title specifically says CSS but if you are ok with JS solution then you could use something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/bcLt62jx/4/).

Comment: Sounds like he might want something like `:nth-last-child(1 of p, ul, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5)` from selectors-4. Basically, it means out of *all* of those element types, select the very last occurrence. So if you have something like `h1 + p + ul + h2 + p + span`, it'll select only the last p.