# CSS not updating after Jquery script - Isotope asymmetrical filterable grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am trying to create an asymmetrical grid filterable grid with Isotope, where asymmetrical means each column has a different margin-top value:

```
.active:nth-child(3n+1) .tile_inner  {margin-top: 280px;}
.active:nth-child(3n+2) .tile_inner  {margin-top: 140px;}
.active:nth-child(3n+3) .tile_inner  {margin-top: 0;}
```

This way, the columns are slightly displaced, as you can see in this Jsfiddle I made:
https://jsfiddle.net/9wrjx9wb/4/

The style is applied not to the tiles themselves (it would screw Isotope calculations) but to a child element inside of them.

Now, the result looks ok when the page is loaded but, as soon as one or more filters are activated (by clicking on the labels on top), the nth child rule seems to be applied incorrectly, even though it should only affect the filtered elements (the ones with the .active class).

Why is this happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: Might it be you thought that with`.active:nth-child(3n+1)` you could achieve `:nth-of-class`? See [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with another selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/1529630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `nth-*` selector here, because it counts all siblings (not just the `.active` ones). You can manually set the margin with a little javascript:

```
$container.find(filter).each(function(i) {       
        var off = (280-(i % 3)*140) + "px";

        $(":first-child",this).css({"margin-top":off});
    });
```

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/yc1ax79b/3/

Comment: Goddamn CSS :( Thank you, Longchiwen, for the solution and the working Jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty neat.

You can't target `.tile_inner` if you want to do this though. The margins of `.tile_inner` cannot affect its parent's margins.

Instead, you can target `.active` and change the padding instead of the margins.

```
.active:nth-child(3n+1)  {padding-top: 280px;}
.active:nth-child(3n+2)  {padding-top: 140px;}
.active:nth-child(3n+3)  {padding-top: 0;}
```

[Check out the fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9wrjx9wb/10/).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the items, when filtered, are still in the DOM and `nth-child` also counts hidden elements and `nth-child` does not work as you'd expect (as you just found :P).

My suggestion is to make use of the `arrangeComplete` event and assign a `first`, `second` and `third` class to the visible elements.

First of all, replace your CSS `nth-child` by these. I added a little transition to make it smoother but it's not perfect.

```
.active.first .tile_inner  { transition: margin-top 0.2s linear; margin-top: 280px;}
.active.second .tile_inner { transition: margin-top 0.2s linear; margin-top: 140px;}
.active.third .tile_inner  { transition: margin-top 0.2s linear; margin-top: 0;}
```

then register the [appropriate event](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/events.html#arrangecomplete)

```
$container.on('arrangeComplete', function(event, filteredItems) {
    $.each(filteredItems, function(i, e) {
        $(e.element).removeClass("first second third").addClass(function() {
            var modulus = i % 3;
            if(modulus == 0) {
                return "first";
            } else if(modulus == 1) {
                return "second";
            } else if(modulus == 2) {
                return "third";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Also I had to add this during startup to invoke the `arrangeComplete` event so that the `first`, `second` and `third` classes are assigned. You can of course avoid this by setting the class yourself. Whatever you prefer :)

```
$container.isotope({ filter: '*' });
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wrjx9wb/15/) that pieces everything together. I hope this can help you get started.

Comment: "arrangeComplete" is triggered only when animation ends, so columns will jump a little when you assign class.

Comment: @longchiwen That's true but that's all the events we are given. Anyway, I just saw your answer and works better ;)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, Ricardo!
As you yourself said, Longchiwen's explanation works better, but I appreciate your work and information!