# Understanding :nth-of-type() and selectors parsed right to left

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know [CSS selectors are parsed right to left](https://css-tricks.com/why-browsers-read-selectors-right-to-left/), and something about `nth-of-type` selector, but I'm confused when I wrote the below code:

```css
#container div {
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#container > div:nth-of-type(2n+1).sub {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="dispear">3</div>
  <div class="sub">4</div>
</div>
```

So, as CSS selectors are parsed right to left, the browser first looks at the `.sub`:

```
<div class="sub">1</div>
<div class="sub">2</div>
<div class="sub">4</div>
```

Then it reads `div:nth-of-type(2n+1)`, first I thought it would match:

```
<div class="sub">1</div>
<div class="sub">4</div>
```

But the result shows that **it only matches `<div class="sub">1</div>`!** Just so weird...

Am I understanding right? Can anyone explain that to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with RTL matching whatsoever, given that the problem lies not with the `#container >` portion but with the `div:nth-of-type(2n+1).sub` portion itself, to which RTL matching simply does not apply. Your assessment of how a browser might evaluate your selector is inaccurate at best.

What RTL matching actually means is that a typical browser walks through the entire DOM, finding candidate rules for *each* element in the DOM and seeing which ones match. This means the browser evaluates *every* one of your `div` elements and evaluates all candidate selectors for *each* element independently. For each selector, the browser starts by comparing the target element against the *key selector*, which is the rightmost *set of simple selectors* after the last combinator (in this case, the entire `div:nth-of-type(2n+1).sub` portion as a single unit), then walks *right to left* through the rest of the complex selector for as long as it continues matching elements in the element subtree.

`:nth-of-type()` counts by element *type*, that is, `div`. That is all. The class is only relevant insofar that the `div` element must have that class in order for the style to be applied, and it doesn't affect the counting of `:nth-of-type()` in any way, which is why `div.dispear` doesn't match despite also being `:nth-of-type(2n+1)`.

See also: [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-another-selector)

Comment: Wow, never knew there was a word call *insofar* :D There is still something to learn in all your posts other than the coding part itself :)

Comment: Nice explanation! I think I got some ideas to solve my problem, thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using `nth-of-type` and the element with `class='disappear` is also a `div` element. The `nth-of-type` selector works directly on the element type and the class condition that you add to it is only an additional condition but not the main one.

Here the selector works this way - Select all `div` elements which is a direct child of the `#container`, matches the `nth-of-type(2n+1)` condition and *in addition* also has `class='sub'`.

```css
#container div, #container p {
  float: left;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#container>div:nth-of-type(2n+1).sub {
  border-color: red;
}

/* just for demo */

#container{
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <div class="sub">1</div> <!-- this would be selected -->
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="sub">3</div> <!-- this would also be selected because it matches both -->
  <div class="sub">4</div>
</div>

<div id='container'>
  <div class="sub">1</div> <!-- this would be selected -->
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <p class="disappear">3</p>
  <div class="sub">4</div> <!-- this would be selected because it is 3rd div and has sub class -->
</div>

<div id='container'>
  <div class="sub">1</div> <!-- this would be selected -->
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="disappear">3</div> <!-- this won't be selected because it is 3rd div but doesn't have the required class -->
  <div class="sub">4</div> <!-- this won't be selected because it has required class but doesn't match nth-of-type(2n+1) which is the primary -->
</div>
```

Comment: Nice follow up Examples with Explanation.