# css: How to skip hidden child in nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even)

Tags: html, css

I am try to skip hidden child while using nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even), but it does not skip those hidden records.

i have the following HTML and CSS code.

```html
<style>
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  li {
    height: 2em;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  /* li:not(.hidden):nth-child(odd) { */
  li:nth-child(odd) {
    background: khaki;
  }
  li:nth-child(even) {
    background: indianred;
  }
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
</style>


<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="hidden">4</li>
  <li class="hidden">5</li>
  <li class="hidden">6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
</ul>
```

I want to list displaying on the browser should have alternative color irrespective of the number of hidden children.

Comment: Would you accept a javascript solution?

Comment: No, i don't want to use java script, i know the solution in js but i am restricted to use js, i have to use css.

Comment: its not possible in CSS, you may need to modify your HTML or go for jquery solution

Comment: Are you able to insert extra LI dummy elements?

Comment: @Musarrat Hussain As this question has been closed, and I still have two more alternatives to propose, you'd better ask it again avoiding to mention "nth-child": Say you just want to give different colours to even/odd rows while some of them are invisible.

Answer (score 4):

If you could change your document's structure, then you could set a different tag for the hidden items, so that you could take advantage of the `:nth-of-type` pseudo-class:

**CSS:**

```
  div.list p {
    height: 2em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
  }
  div.list p:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background: khaki;
  }
  div.list p:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: indianred;
  }
  .hidden {
    display: none;
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list">
  <p>1</p>
  <p>2</p>
  <p>3</p>
  <span class="hidden">4</span>
  <span class="hidden">5</span>
  <span class="hidden">6</span>
  <p>7</p>
  <p>8</p>
  <p>9</p>
  <p>10</p>
  <p>11</p>
</div>
```

Comment: if we change the type of the element that you have done then its working, but i can not change the type of the element. as based on some event the hidden class may change, then i have to change the type of the element as well.

Answer (score 3):

As [this answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5546296/778975) there is currently no way to do this purely with CSS. You could work around this by altering the code that hides the `li` elements so that it inserts a another hidden dummy element after the hidden item to even things out and make it look right, and then remove that dummy item when you un-hide it.

```
var hide = function (el) {
    el.classList.add('hidden');
    el.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<li class="hidden dummy"></li>');
  },
  show = function (el) {
    if (el.classList.contains('hidden')) {
      el.classList.remove('hidden');
      el.parentNode.removeChild(el.nextElementSibling);
    }
  };
```

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/y7L4zu0a/)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to remove the hidden elements from the DOM, rather than just hide them.

Comment: As all the child are created dynamically and will switch to hidden/show on different event, so i am not able to remove and add all these child on each and every event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-another-selector