# select second active slide in slickslider through css-selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using slick slider and showing 3 slides, I would like to add specific styling on the center slide. by using nth-of-type but it seems to fail when I add .slick-active:nth-of-type(2) any ideas?

for example:

```
<div class="slickslider">
    <div class="slick-slide"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-current slick-active"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide slick-active"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide"></div>
    <div class="slick-slide"></div>
</div>



.slick-slide{
      background: blue;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 1px;
    }
    .slick-active{
      background: green;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
    }
    .slick-active:nth-of-type(2){
      background: pink;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pixelatorz/73scpych/2/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-another-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way by playing process of elimination:

```
.slickslider .slick-active + .slick-active:nth-child(odd){
    background: pink !important;
}
```

See [**demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Wrpxom)

Basically, eliminate the first one with the `+` and next, eliminate the last one by choosing the `odd` child. Or first child would've worked too

**EDIT**

If you think there will be more than 3 active slides in the future and you want to make this more dependable, I suggest you wrap the active slides in a `<span>` and class it active-slides or something similar. Then. you will be able to select through them with `nth-child` without using `.slickslider` as a parent.

Answer (score 0):

Is a stupid solution, but works:

```
.slick-slide:nth-of-type(6){
  background: pink;
}
```

Comment: It works, but I'm afraid that he wants to select through the active slides only. My guess is that he could potentially have a different qty of slides all together, but only 3 actives ones. OP wasn't very clear about that. You may still be right :)

Comment: yeah true, only the active slides I want to select, those keep changing as long while the slider is looping