# How to use "not: and "nth-of-type filters" for filtering html tags cssselector webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Let us assume I have the DOM structure as follows in a big HTML file:

```
<ul class="results">
    <li class="hai bye">Coffee</li>
    <li class="hai">Tea</li>
    <li class="hai bye">Milk</li>
    <li class="hai">Soup</li>
    <li class="hai bye">Soft Drinks</li>
</ul>
```

I wanted select the second list element which does not contain class "bye" using cssselector webdriver.

I have tried writing the cssselector as : 
`.results li.hai:not(.bye):nth-of-type(%d)`, it didn't work.

But, if I tried writing cssselector like: `.results li.hai:not(.bye)`, it is selecting the first list element "Tea" which is not having class "bye".
So, the `nth-of-type` is not working.

Am I using nth-of-type wrongly? Please guide me.

Output I need is to select the "Soup" list element.

Comment: You'll need to select all the `.results li.hai:not(.bye)` elements and grab the 2nd one separately.

Comment: Thanks, It worked!! But can't we use both the filters at one go?

Comment: No, you can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-another-selector

Answer (score 0):

Use `.results li:nth-of-type(4) {}` for soup.

Comment: Actually the tag with class "bye" will hide the element from the page. Let say I want to select a list element which is in first position, as the first list element is hidden, the selenium is not able to locate the element. So, I have to filter out which are all the tags that do not contain class "bye" and then select the nth file accordingly. So, hard coding doesn't work for me.

Comment: Adding some explanation of your answer will help others who come later to get some use out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `nth-of-type` correctly but it will take nth element from `li` not for specific class. You can use xpath selector as `//li[@class='hai'][2]`.

Comment: Thanks! But, I want to do it with css selector. Selecting all the list elements which is not having class "bye" and grabbing the nth element worked as suggested above.