# Skip some row in odd and even colored rows in a table -- continuous CSS style

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a HTML table and I want an odd/even sequence colored rows, but excluding `.SectionHeader` class and continue its sequence style where it leaves off.

```css
tr:not(.SectionHeader):nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color:#fff;
}
tr:not(.SectionHeader):nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color:#f0f9ff;
}
tr.SectionHeader{background: red;}
```

```html
<table class="pvk_table">
    <thead>
      <tr class="SectionHeader">
          <th colspan="3">BÖLÜM / PROGRAM</th>
          <th colspan="2">2015 ÖSYS TABAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th>
          <th colspan="2">2015 ÖSYS TAVAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr class="SectionHeader">
        <th>İktisadi ve İdari Bilimler Fakültesi</th>
        <th>Puan Türü</th>
        <th>Kontenjan</th>
        <th>Puan</th>
        <th>Sıralama</th>
        <th>Puan</th>
        <th>Sıralama</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr><tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr class="SectionHeader">
          <th colspan="3">BÖLÜM / PROGRAM</th>
          <th colspan="2">2015 ÖSYS TABAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th>
          <th colspan="2">2015 ÖSYS TAVAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
        <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>İktisat</td>
        <td>TM-1</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>416,44977</td>
        <td>13927</td>
        <td>458,45591</td>
        <td>3081</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I also want the blue color row after the third red header in this table.
Please suggest what I should do, I am getting stuck on this issue.

Comment: The is no nth-of-class selector so you will probably need javascript.

Comment: What is it that you want exactly, The 3rd row is blue and everything that follows alternates white blue. I assumed you wanted that header below to be red since you weren't specific. Or did you want it blue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **UPDATE 2**

OP: *is this possible to do without to add this extra `<tr>` with `.row0` class ?*

Yes, there most certainly is an alternative and on hindsight, a better and more valid way is to use another `<tbody>`.

[**MDN:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody)

> ...multiple <tbody> elements are permitted (if consecutive), allowing the data-rows in **long tables** to be divided into different sections, **each separately formatted** as needed.

**Change:**

```
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: #fff; }
tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #f0f9ff; }
```

**to:**

```
tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: #fff; }
tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #f0f9ff; }
```

and **Add:**

```
</tbody>
<tbody>
```

Before the last `tr.SectionHeader`

**Snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Increased Specificity and Row 0</title>
<style>
tbody tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: #fff; }
tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #f0f9ff; }
tr.SectionHeader.SectionHeader { background: red; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table class="pvk_table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
      <th colspan="3">BÖLÜM / PROGRAM</th> <th colspan="2">2015 ÖSYS TABAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th> <th colspan="2">2015 ÖSYS TAVAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
      <th>İktisadi ve İdari Bilimler Fakültesi</th> <th>Puan Türü</th> <th>Kontenjan</th> <th>Puan</th> <th>Sıralama</th> <th>Puan</th> <th>Sıralama</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>     
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
      <th colspan="3" >BÖLÜM / PROGRAM</th> <th colspan="2" >2015 ÖSYS TABAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th> <th colspan="2" >2015 ÖSYS TAVAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

---

---

## **UPDATE**

After rereading, editing, and then rereading the OP, I finally understand the issue and I have an updated solution to this question. All code posted previously is still relevant and required with this update.

Basically, OP couldn't get a blue row to proceed the red header at the lower end of the table. So after reading @BoltClock♦ [post on this matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector), it suddenly dawned on me that all that was needed was to insert or remove a row. I opted to insert an extra row, but I thought that any changes to the tables dimensions may cause difficulties in layout. So I came up with this:

> Do not copy & paste this code it is chopped up in fragments so you 
>   don't have scroll when reading.

**CSS**

> `.row0` has width but no height (a line). This style allows `.row0` to exist 
>   in a table as a valid `<tr>` without altering or disturbing the table visually and layout wise.

```
 tr.row0 { height: 0; border-spacing: 0; border: none; font-size: 0; 
 margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0; }
```

**HTML**

> .row0 markup is just as minimal as it's style. Here we have an empty `<tr>` 
>   (no children like `<td>`). Make sure that `.row0` is inserted anywhere *before*
>    the target row you plan to bump.

```
 <tr class="row0"></tr>
```

Now the end result is:

- All `.SectionHeader` are red.
- All odd `<tr>` (with the exception of headers) are white.
- All even `<tr>` (with the exception of headers) are blue.
- Most importantly, the color of the row that proceeds the third header is now blue.

  ---

  ---

**The code featured earlier still applies.**

To make the alternating colored rows, reference the `<tbody>` then the `<tr>`

Here's a little known trick that works just like `!important`

*Double up your `.class` on a ruleset*

Check it out:

```
tr.SectionHeader.SectionHeader {background: red;}
```

Now every `.SectionHeader` is red like it should've been. To test it, try removing a class:

```
tr.SectionHeader {background: red;}
```

You'll see that not every `.SectionHeader` is red now. This trick increases the selector's specificity yet it's not entirely as limiting as `!important`.

## [**Updated Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FgYqX9gwfBQS76PrTdyd?p=preview)

## **Updated Snippet**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Increased Specificity and Row 0</title>
<style>
tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background-color: #fff; }
tr:nth-of-type(even) { background-color: #f0f9ff; }
tr.SectionHeader.SectionHeader { background: red; }
tr.row0 { height: 0; border-spacing: 0; border: none; font-size: 0; margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 0; }
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table class="pvk_table">
  <thead>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
      <th colspan="3">BÖLÜM / PROGRAM</th> <th colspan="2">2015 ÖSYS TABAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th> <th colspan="2">2015 ÖSYS TAVAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
      <th>İktisadi ve İdari Bilimler Fakültesi</th> <th>Puan Türü</th> <th>Kontenjan</th> <th>Puan</th> <th>Sıralama</th> <th>Puan</th> <th>Sıralama</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>

     <tr class="row0">
     <!-- Row 0 is an invisible line that forces the `nth-*` rows to skip the zebra strip pattern -->
    </tr>
    <tr class="SectionHeader">
      <th colspan="3" >BÖLÜM / PROGRAM</th> <th colspan="2" >2015 ÖSYS TABAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th> <th colspan="2" >2015 ÖSYS TAVAN GENEL KONTENJAN</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="hidden-xs">İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>İktisat</td> <td>TM-1</td> <td>100</td> <td>416,44977</td> <td>13927</td> <td>458,45591</td> <td>3081</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi downvoter, why do you believe this answer is wrong? Please, enlighten me. :-)

Comment: ya this is exactly i want thank you so much and one thing is this possible to do without to add this extra tr with row0 class ???

Comment: ya zerOOne i have already check that

Comment: Thanks @Darshanambaliya. See update 2.

Comment: So much effort and no upvotes... Take mine, you saved me a bunch of work :)

Comment: IKR? Thanks, @brickBreaker I'm glad I could help 