# CSS: How can i select the last not empty child (in my case <li>)?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is not working

```
.users ul li:last-child:not(:empty) span.number { 
   text-indent: 20px; 
   background: url('../images/remove.png') center center no-repeat; 
}
```

It works selecting the first-child but i do not need it.

```
.users ul li:first-child:not(:empty) span.number
```

[Example of what I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s80rA.png)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Actually, I suspect that the `first-child` one isn't working...it's just a co-incidence. `last-child` ***only*** selects the very last child regardless of other criteria, you're looking for `last-of-class`...which does not exist.

Comment: is there any element after the last li??

Comment: Duplicate? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Comment: Gaurav there are only <li> allowed inside a <ul>. In my case a have 4 non empty <li> and 2 empty <li> . You can watch it from the photo attached in the question.

Comment: Paulie you are saying that there is no solution?

Comment: Javascript is probably the solution. And why would you have empty `li` in the first place?

Comment: @Paulie_D: Even without seeing the markup, there's a 90% chance that's the answer.