# Selecting a class with odd and even that contains a specific class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, selector

Consider the following code (using sass):

```css
#wrapper {
  .switch-element:nth-child(even) {
  }
  
  .switch-element:nth-child(odd) {
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="normal-element">Element that needs to stay the same and should not be counted.</div>
  <div class="normal-element">Element that needs to stay the same and should not be counted.</div>
  <div class="switch-element">Element that needs to change and should be counted.</div>
  <div class="normal-element">Element that needs to stay the same and should not be counted.</div>
  <div class="switch-element">Element that needs to change and should be counted.</div>
</div>
```

This will count every child of wrapper, making the first element "normal-element", "1" (odd), the second element "normal-element", "2" (even), the third element "switch-element", "3" (odd), the fourth element "normal-element", "4" (even), the fifth element "switch-element", "5" (odd).

I want to make it so that it ignores all the normal-elements, and only counts the switch-elements. Making the first switch-element odd and the second switch-element even.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

What you want in fact is `:nth-of-class` selector, which would work similarly to `:nth-of-type(2n)` (select even children of type) and `:nth-of-type(2n+1)` (select odd children of type).

Sadly there's no such selector and it's not possible to do with structure you have. You would need to either group divs OR change divs to other elements like `section` and use `:nth-of-type` (very weird, definitely not recommended) OR just render additional `odd`/`even` class for all elements.

See: [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)