# Unexpected behaviour from :nth-of-type(n+1)

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm an avid user of the `x-of-type` family of CSS pseudo-classes:

- `:first-of-type`
- `:last-of-type`
- `:nth-of-type`
- `:nth-last-of-type`

I am usually fairly adept at ensuring that any series of similar elements (list items etc.) displays exactly as I wish it to.

In the last hour, however, I have been stuck on how to achieve the following result with a single style declaration:

- Item 1 has a `border-bottom`
- Item 2 has a `border-bottom`
- Item 3 has a `border-bottom`
- Item 4 (the last item) has no `border-bottom`

I have achieved what I need, using:

```
.item {
border-bottom:6px solid rgb(227,227,227);
}

.item:last-of-type {
border-bottom:none;
}
```

but for the purposes of brevity, I'd still prefer to achieve the same result with a single declaration.

**Question:**

Why won't

```
.item:nth-of-type(n-1) {
    border-bottom:6px solid rgb(227,227,227);
    }
```

or

```
.item:nth-last-of-type(n+1) {
    border-bottom:6px solid rgb(227,227,227);
    }
```

work?

Is it because `n` is simply an infinite list of numbers, including numbers before and after the number of targeted elements on the page?

If so, how can I declare *"Everything but the last item"* in a single declaration?

*(And apologies in advance, if it's something really obvious and I've just failed to notice it...)*

---

## Added...

Here is the HTML I'm working with:

```
<aside>
<img src="" title="" alt="" />
<span class="something-else">Blah</span>
<span class="item">Item Details</span>

<img src="" title="" alt="" />
<span class="something-else">Blah</span>
<span class="item">Item Details</span>

<img src="" title="" alt="" />
<span class="something-else">Blah</span>
<span class="item">Item Details</span>

<img src="" title="" alt="" />
<span class="something-else">Blah</span>
<span class="item">Item Details</span>
</aside>
```

Comment: The class selector is misleading; you might want to add or replace it with a type selector to make it clear that you're not confusing :*-of-type with a hypothetical :*-of-class selector - or better yet, replace it with :*-child.

Comment: The `:nth-of-type` pseudo-class selects elements, not classes of elements, so adding a class like `.item` in front of it is like adding a filter that will only be applied if the last of of the type you target has that class. You should post the HTML you're targeting so we can see what you're working with.

Comment: Ahhhh... so you can't apply `x-of-type` to _classes_? That might explain why I've been scratching my head for the last hour...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it because `n` is simply an infinite list of numbers, including numbers before and after the number of targeted elements on the page?

Yes, that's why `:nth-of-type(n-1)` appears to match every element: `n` counts an infinite number of times. So the last of type will still match, when `n` is 1 plus the total number of children of that element type. In other words, the expression `n-b` for any `b` (or `n+b` for `b <= 1`) is equivalent to `n` (itself `n-0`), which is a guaranteed match.

`:nth-last-of-type(n+1)` is close, but the reason that doesn't do what you want is because `n` starts counting from zero, so when `n` is zero, `n+1` matches the last of type.

> If so, how can I declare *"Everything but the last item"* in a single declaration?

You have two ways. One that you were close to is `:nth-last-of-type(n+2)`. The other is the much clearer `:not(:last-of-type)`.

Comment: `:nth-last-of-type(n+2)` ! Of course. If I'd thought just a little bit harder, I would have got there. That's perfect - concise and elegant. Many thanks, BoltClock.

Answer (score 2):

Try this selector:

```
.item:not(:last-of-type) {
    border-bottom:6px solid rgb(227,227,227);
}
```

It select all elements with the class `item`, that are `:not` the `:last-of-type`.

Note that you can use `:not()` with any **single** piece of a selector.

```
/* This is valid */
p:not(.classA):not(.classB):not(.classC) {
    /* ... */
}

/* This isn’t: */
p:not(.classA.classB.classC) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Great work, @J F - many thanks. I'm going to shy away from `:not` on this occasion (as on many others) - but not because I have any rational or any reasonable justification for doing so. I appreciate your excellent answer. Thank you.