# CSS: how to target the nth direct child

Tags: css

On [this page](http://www.staffordshirelodge.com.au/), I'd like to get rid of the white space below the testimonials and above the footer:

[image]

The following CSS is not working:

```css
 body > .container:nth-child(2) {display:none;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 centered">
   <h3 class="border"><span>abc</span></h3>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row adoption">
       xyz
   <!-- Display 3 Adoption -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Can you help me understand why please?

Comment: What element is **this area**?

Comment: can you provide more code to understand your problem?

Comment: why don't you remove the div from the page directly instead of display:none?

Comment: This might help ```body > .container {display: none;}```

Comment: @Justinas, it's the code underneath the screen shot.

Comment: Are you sure the second child of the body has a `container` class assigned to it? The image makes me think it is later down the line and might not even be a direct child of the body.

Specifity can also be an issue here if another style also affects the `display` property of that element. In most browsers you can right-click on an element and select `inspect element`. This way you can see which part of the stylesheet(s) is responsible for a specific style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, this works: `body > .container:nth-child(9) {  display: none;  }`

**UPDATE**: I'm mentally smacking myself for not realizing this... `nth-child` is the number it is in the order. It is not filtered by the class. Something a little closer is `nth-of-type`, but that just filters by the element tag and if it has the class. Taking the second element with the class is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649) without a pure CSS solution unfortunately.

Comment: Nice one. I thought I was counting correctly. There must of been some intermediate `.container`s buried above.

Answer (score 0):

Use you need to target `.row:nth-child(2)` to hide second row.

```css
.container .row {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
}
.container .row:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 centered">
      <h3 class="border"><span></span></h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row adoption">
    <!-- Display 3 Adoption -->
  </div>
</div>
```