# Stop inbetween div from breaking the nth-child sequence

Tags: html, css

I have a nth-child question. 
For example, I have a set of divs where I am using nth-child(odd) to target the odd elements to do some stuff as in the following example
http://codepen.io/hellouniverse/pen/apvWpE

Now, it works until there is a div in between that breaks the whole sequence as can be seen with class voyager.

How can I maintain the sequence?

The html used for demo is

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="test">Hello World</div>
    <div class="test2">Hello Earth</div>


    <div class="test">Hello World</div>
    <div class="test2">Hello Earth</div>


    <div class="test">Hello World</div>
    <div class="test2">Hello Earth</div>


    <div class="test">Hello World</div>
    <div class="test2">Hello Earth</div>

    <div class="voyager"> I AM GOING TO BREAK UYOU </div>


    <div class="test">Hello World</div>
    <div class="test2">Hello Earth</div>


    <div class="test">Hello World</div>
    <div class="test2">Hello Earth</div>


    <div class="test">Hello World</div>
    <div class="test2">Hello Earth</div>


    <div class="test">Hello World</div>
    <div class="test2">Hello Earth</div>


</div>
```

And the css used for demo is

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    .test {
        color: red;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        height: 20px;
    }

    .test2 {
        color: blue;
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
        height: 20px;
    }

    div:nth-child(odd) {
        color: grey;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not target odd element using `.test ` itself?

Comment: This is not how `nth-child`/`nth-of-type` work. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/1492578

Comment: @JohnBupit How is this a duplicate of that?

Comment: Your code shown here is different from codepen

Comment: @Mr.Alien The OP is trying to add an `:nth-of-type` on a class selector `.test` (see the codepen link in the question), which is what is asked in the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
.test {
    color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
}

.test2 {
    color: blue;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
    color: grey;
}
div.voyager ~ div:nth-child(even){
    color: grey;
}
div.voyager ~ div:nth-child(odd){
    color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'nth-' selector just counts elements, disregarding class. There is, unfortunately, no 'nth-of-class()'...

The only way I see around that would be to change your 'voyager' class element to some other type, such as span