# nth-of-type doesn't work as expected

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="test1"></div>
    <div class="test2"></div>
    <div class="test3"></div>
</div>
```

why

```
.test3:nth-of-type(3) {height: 100px;background: black;}
```

work, but

```
.test3:nth-of-type(1) {height: 100px;background: black;}
```

not? Is nth-type-of work same as nth-child in this case?

Comment: You only have one `test3`, why use `nth-of-type`?

Comment: it should be .test:nth-of-type(1){} .test:nth-of-type(3){}..........

Comment: just give a simple example,i found this in other case?And i want to know the reason

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The nth-of-type pseudo selector is certainly working here as expected.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type):

> The :nth-of-type(an+b) CSS pseudo-class matches an element that has
>   an+b-1 siblings with the same element name before it in the document
>   tree

So

```
.test3:nth-of-type(3) {height: 100px;background: black;}
```

'works' because the div with class test3 also happens to be the third div within the container (div with class test)

however

```
.test3:nth-of-type(1) {height: 100px;background: black;}
```

doesn't select the test3 div because it isn't the first div in the container

> Is `nth-of-type` work same as `nth-child` in this case?

In this case they are the same because all of the children in the container are divs.

---

In general, it could help to think about pseudo classes as a **filter** which matches only a subset of the matched selector (ie the part of the selector before the colon) when it is in the **state** that the pseudo class describes.

So for example `.test:hover` means: select all elements with class test - but only the ones which are being hovered.

Similarly here with nth-of-type: `.test3:nth-of-type(3)` means:

Select all elements with class test3, but only if it's the 3rd of that kind of element within it's container.

So take the following demo:

```css
.test:nth-of-type(3) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="test">li 1</li>
    <li class="test">li 2</li>
    <li class="test">li 3</li>
    <li class="test">li 4</li>
    <li class="test">li 5</li>
  </ul>
  <span class="test">span 1</span>
  <span class="test">span 2</span>
  <span class="test">span 3</span>
  <span class="test">span 4</span>
  <span class="test">span 5</span>
</div>
```

Notice that both the third list item and the third span are styled - that's because both have class test and are the third of that kind of element within their container

### NB:

When using an `nth-of-type` pseudo class **without** limiting it with a [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) - **all types will match** - as if the universal selector was used.

So for example:

`.test:nth-of-type(3)` is equivalent to `*.test:nth-of-type(3)`

Demo:

```css
.test:nth-of-type(3) {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <fred class="test">fred 1</fred>
  <div class="test">div 1</div>
  <span class="test">span 1</span>
  <p class="test">p 1</p>
  <p class="test">p 2</p>
  <p class="test">p 3</p>
  <p class="test">p 4</p>
  <span class="test">span 2</span>
  <fred class="test">fred 2</fred>
  <fred class="test">fred 3</fred>
  <span class="test">span 3</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! that is right.By the way, do you have any idea to select something like nth-of-class

Comment: Unfortunately, CSS doesn't have a `nth-of-class` selector - see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Nice answer, well explained!

Answer (score 1):

You use `.test3` in your selectors, but a class `.test3` does only occure one time in your markup. So there are no other elements of `.test3`.

You can use `.test > div` to access your direct child divs.

Also, the pattern for `nth-of-type` is `:nth-of-type( <an-plus-b> )`. So you can just use

```
.test > div:nth-of-type(2n+1) { ... } /* or */
.test > div:nth-of-type(odd) { ... }
```

to get the first and the third (every odd) element.

```css
.test>div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.test > div:nth-of-type(2n+1) {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">1</div>
  <div class="test2">2</div>
  <div class="test3">3</div>
</div>
```

You can also just access the single child you need with `.test > div:nth-of-type(1)`:

```css
.test>div {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.test > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="test1">1</div>
  <div class="test2">2</div>
  <div class="test3">3</div>
</div>
```

See more information about [`nth-of-type` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type).

Answer (score 1):

```
.test3:nth-of-type(1) {height: 100px;background: black;}
```

is not working because the **type** refers to div and since you have no first child element as div with a class of *test3* the css is not applied to it.

If your markup was written like in the example below that selector would work but the selector

```
.test3:nth-of-type(3) {height: 100px;background: black;}
```

would not because there is no 3rd element of the type div and class *test3*

Maybe you'll figure of the importance of the type word in this selector by adding some elements of another type before the first div like in the example below

```css
.test3:nth-of-type(1) {height: 100px;background: black; color: #fff;}
```

```html
        <div class="test">
         <p class="paragraph">1st eleement of paragraph type</p>
         <div class="test3">1st element of div type</div>
         <div class="test2">2nd element of div type</div>
         <div class="test1">3rd element of div type</div>
        </div>
```