# Two nth-child(odds) for different class named rows in one table

Tags: css

I have a table with 50 entries, some of which have a class of 'event' or 'comment.'  Here is what the table row entries look like:

Event, Comment, Event, Comment, Comment, Comment, Event

What I want to do is alternate the row colors of both the 'event' and 'comment' class names separately.  Currently what I have is this:

```
tr.event:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #000;
}
tr.comment:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

With this code, I get an output of:

Black (event), White (comment), Black (event), White (comment), Black (comment), White (comment), Black (event)

I want the output to be this:

Black (event), Black (comment), White (event), White (comment), Black (comment), White (comment), Black (event)

Any help would be great!

Comment: `nth-child` refers to the order of the child within its parent, not within all children with some shared class. So basically, you can't do this in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible with pure css.

A very good reply to the same issue can be found here: [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

What I recommend is: add a new class to each odd element and style that one accordingly.

So you will have

```
.comment
.event
.comment.odd
.event.odd
.event
.event.odd
.comment
```

Etc

Otherwise, you can do it using js. But the extra class method should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to represent what is essentially hierarchical data with a non-hierarchical HTML structure. `nth-child` refers to the order of the child within its parent, not within all children with some shared class. So basically, you can't do this in CSS.

Try structuring your HTML like this if you can:

```
<div>

  <div class="event">
    <div class="comment"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="event">
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="event">
  </div>

</div>
```

Now you can style this with

```
.event:nth-child(odd)    { color: white; }
.event:nth-child(even)   { color: black; }
.comment:nth-child(odd)  { color: white; }
.comment:nth-child(even) { color: black; }
```

Since you seem to want to start the comments with the same color as the event it is part of, you would need to do:

```
.event:nth-child(odd) { color: white; }
.event:nth-child(odd) .comment:nth-child(odd) { color: white; }
.event:nth-child(odd) .comment:nth-child(even) { color: black; }

.event:nth-child(even) { color: black; }
.event:nth-child(even) .comment:nth-child(odd) { color: black; }
.event:nth-child(even) .comment:nth-child(even) { color: white; }
```

The above uses `div` elements. But if you really want to do this with a table, you could try using the following HTML, then use the same kind of logic as above:

```
<table>

  <thead><tr><td>Event</td></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Comment</td></tr>
  </tbody>

  <thead <tr><td>Event</td></tr></thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Comment</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Comment</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Comment</td></tr>
  </tbody>

  <thead><tr><td>Event</td></tr></thead>

</table>
```

Then write:

```
thead:nth-of-type(odd) { color: white; }
tbody:nth-of-type(even) tr:nth-child(odd) { color: white; }
tbody:nth-of-type(odd)  tr:nth-child(event) { color: black; }

thead:nth-of-type(even) { color: black; }
tbody:nth-of-type(even) tr:nth-child(odd) { color: black; }
tbody:nth-of-type(odd)  tr:nth-child(event) { color: white; }
```

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible with pure CSS, you will have to use jQuery to add a class (or the style directly if you wish).

jQuery's indexing starts a 0, so what it considers even, we consider odd.

I've added the color green so that you can see what's in the cell.

```js
$('table').each(function() {
  $('tr.comment:even').addClass('odd');
  $('tr.event:even').addClass('odd');
});
```

```css
tr.comment.odd {
  background-color: #000;
}

tr.event.odd {
  background-color: #000;
}

table {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="event">
    <td>event</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="comment">
    <td>comment</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="event">
    <td>event</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="comment">
    <td>comment</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="comment">
    <td>comment</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="comment">
    <td>comment</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="event">
    <td>event</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```