# CSS need to target 2nd row of a table with a class

Tags: html, css

I have this code in my HTML file. I need to target second `<tr>` with class `detail-row` and  within the `<tr>` I need to target the `.k-grouping-row` class for a `<tr>`.

How can I target this using CSS?  I tried `nth-child`, but it didn't work with the class names.

```
<table>
  <tr class="master-row" ></tr>
  <tr class="detail-row" ></tr>
  <tr class="master-row" ></tr>
  <tr class="detail-row" >

    <td class="k-detail-cell" colspan="5">
      <div class="k-grid k-widget">
        <div class="k-grid-header" >
          <div class="k-grid-header-wrap >
            <table role="grid">
              <thead role="rowgroup">
                <tr role="row">
                  <th class="k-group-cell k-header" scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="k-grid-content k-auto-scrollable" style="height: 0px;">
          <table role="grid">
            <tbody role="rowgroup">
              <tr role="row" class="k-grouping-row"></tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>

  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: please fix the element tags first.

Comment: you don't have any cells in your rows - that's invalid HTML.

Comment: Target it by calling its class name in css: `.k-grouping-row { background-color: black; }`

Comment: [Helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5546296/17300) about `:nth-child` and `nth-of-type` etc. indicates the best you can do is know that rows are in master + detail pairs, and select the _fourth_ `tr:nth-child(4)` row to get the _second_ detail-row ... as some answers have indicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the nth-child selector, and select the k-grouping-row by its class:

```css
tr:nth-child(2) {
  color: lime;
}

.k-grouping-row {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="master-row">
    <td>master row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail-row">
    <td>detail row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="master-row">
    <td>master row</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="detail-row">

    <td class="k-detail-cell" colspan="5">
      <div class="k-grid k-widget">
        <div class="k-grid-header">
          <div class="k-grid-header-wrap >
            <table role=" grid ">
            <thead role="rowgroup ">
            <tr role="row ">
            <th class="k-group-cell k-header " scope="col ">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="k-grid-content k-auto-scrollable " style="height: 0px ">
            <table role="grid ">
            <tbody role="rowgroup ">
            <tr role="row " class="k-grouping-row ">
                <td>k-grouping-row</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Kendo UI huh?

First things first you have a missing double quote in your code at line 10 ("k-grid-header-wrap").

Now for the CSS part, you could use nth-child like you described.

```
tr.detail-row:nth-child(4) .k-grouping-row{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

As with @Johannes' answer, the nth-child is a 4 because your target is the 4th child of its parent. This means you must use that exact HTML or else the CSS will not work.

On the other hand you can use

```
tr.detail-row ~ tr.detail-row .k-grouping-row{
  background-color:blue;
}
tr.detail-row ~ tr.detail-row ~ tr.detail-row .k-grouping-row{
  background-color:inherit;
}
```

The ~ character looks for the next selector specified no matter what is on its way (as long as the selector is a sibling of your element).

Answer (score 1):

The CSS selector would be

```
tr.detail-row tr.k-grouping-row { ... }
```

However, you probably want to address one or all cells in that row, so you'd have to add that

Addition: If the second row also contains a `.k-grouping-row` element, then you'd have to be more precise:

```
table > tr.detail-row:nth-of-type(4) tr.k-grouping-row { ... }
```