# Apply CSS when exists one child with specific class

Tags: html, css, less

I have a dynamic HTML structure and I want to apply a CSS rule only when exists one element that contains one specific class.

```
<div class="inline-container">
   <div class="form-element>
      <label class="paragraph">Some text</label>   
      <div class="select-wrapper">
         <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden">
   <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

When the inputs type are enabled their structure change to the same of "form-element" and of course with the same classes. I only want to apply styles when there are one enabled like in the code. The styles that I want to apply are for the label and for the select. I have tried using only-child or only-of-type but doesn't work fine for that case.

```
label:only-child {
    padding: 0% 29% 0% 0% !important;
}
div:only-child {
    select {
        padding: 0% 10% 0% 59% !important;
    }
}
```

The HTML cannot be modified only the CSS (.less file)

Comment: Could you show example markup where you would want the selector to apply?

Comment: Related - I think - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Also - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Comment: Do you need to apply special styling to `label` and `select` elements inside the `div.form-element` if and only if it is the only `div` inside `.inline-container`? If so, selector like `.inline-container div:only-of-type label, .inline-container div:only-of-type select` should help.

Comment: @IlyaStreltsyn it works but only for the label, for the select is applying the style if there are one or more enabled. We are more near to find the solution... :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code, please note, the padding will not work for the select so can use `appearance:none` .

I'd placed the label below the select wrapper and used `flex` to move it up.

```css
label{
    padding: 0% 29% 0% 0%;
}
.select-wrapper + label{
   padding: 0% 0% 0% 0%;
}
div:only-child select{
   padding: 0% 10% 0% 59% !important;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.form-element {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-flow: column wrap;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
}
.paragraph {
 -webkit-box-ordinal-group: -1;
 -moz-box-ordinal-group: -1;
 -webkit-order: -1;
 -ms-flex-order: -1;
 order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-container">
   <div class="form-element">
      <div class="select-wrapper">
         <select>
            <option value="1">1</option>
         </select>
      </div>
      <label class="paragraph">Some text</label> 
   </div>
   <input type="hidden">
   <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but the HTML cannot be modified I only have to work on the styles. So this solution is not working fine for me...

Comment: i tried with your code as well, and its working fine, https://jsfiddle.net/sandymizz/hf459qoa/2/

Comment: When there are two or more "form-elements" is not doing nothing (that's fine) but when there's only one is not applying the padding :(