# Can CSS count nth-child together with :not?

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to put a clear break after div elements of **those that only are visible**, in pure CSS. Since there is no such :visible selector in CSS, I tried to add a class named hidden into the div elements that should hide.

```css
.box.hidden {
  background: red;
}
.box:not(.hidden):nth-child(4n+1) {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
/* try then without :not() and see the difference
.box:nth-child(4n+1) {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
*/
```

```html
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
```

But I cant get it to work, seems like the **nth-child(4n+1)** only listens to **.box** and not the **:not(.hidden)** rule.

If only this is not possible without javascript/jQuery, a simple jQuery selector solution as an alternative would also work as a solution.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: your question is unclear. do you want `clear: both;` for all visible divs?

Comment: I've converted your code to a snippet so we can see what's going on but I had to guess at the styles for `.box` and `.hidden`. Please correct if required

Comment: This requires JS. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Comment: @Phil  i don't think `.box { float: left; margin: 1ex; }` is required there. It totally changed the output from previous one

Comment: @AlivetoDie like I said, I had to guess. I would think OP is floating the divs and wants to clear every visible 5th one. Having `clear: both` won't do anything unless something is floated

Comment: I have just updated my question with a snippet, where you can see whats going on

Comment: Yes, I would like to clear:both; for all visible divs. But the upper question is more that it seems like the css nth-child() does not count properly when its being used together with :not() - see snippet

Comment: @Karem Looks like it'll be natively possible as a level 4 selector. Until then, you'll have to stick it out with jQuery I imagine.

Comment: @Karem I just added a relatively simple JS example to my answer. Basically, select your elements, filter them out, then apply the style. If you're daring, you could even make a polyfill with this.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer your question, *"no"*, `nth-child` does not work like that.

> The **`:nth-child()`** CSS pseudo-class matches one or more elements based on **their position among a group of siblings**.

It does not take into account the selector when determining sibling position. [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) sort of does but only based on the element type and not on any arbitrary selector.

See the example here ~ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#Result

---

I'd recommend using a flex layout instead of floats and clears.

For example

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  flex: 0 1 25%;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
  <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
  <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
  <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
  <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
  <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
  <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
  <div class="box">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not really answering the question / solution. The question is about how to select appropriately since :nth-child() behaves differently when :not() is used.

Comment: @Karem I've updated my answer with some disappointing information on `nth-child`

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported natively in CSS3, but will be in the level 4 selector specification. Naturally, this doesn't show anything right now, as it's not yet supported.

In the level 4 spec, it should be possible to do the following

```css
.box.hidden {
  background: red;
}
.box:nth-child(4n+1 of :not(.hidden)) {
  border: 5px solid green;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
```

Here's the [formal specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#nth-child-pseudo), which is currently an editor's draft. Example 43 is the one of interest here.

In the meantime, it is possible to use JavaScript to do this, though it is quite tedious. To do what you asked, you'd have to do this

```js
Array.from(
 document.querySelectorAll('.box:not(.hidden)')
).filter(
 (val, index, a) => index % 4 == 0
).forEach(
 elem => elem.style['border'] = '5px solid green'
);
```

```css
.box.hidden {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box hidden">Dont show</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
    <div class="box">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with jquery :

```
$('.box').each(function(el,i){
  $(this).not('.hidden').html('<br/>'); //or $(this).not('.hidden').css('clear','both');
});
```