# first-child and nth-child on selectors

Tags: css

I'm trying to understand why this doesn't work properly.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
}

header a:first-child {
  margin-right: auto;
  border: solid 1px #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <i>something</i>
  <a href="#">a</a>
  <a href="#">b</a>
  <a href="#">c</a>
  <a href="#">d</a>
</header>
```

I'm trying to push everything to the right starting from the first anchor tag (a)

It works with header a:nth-child(2), which is just looking for the second element of header. What then is the point of using a selector (a:)?

Comment: Because the link isn't the **first child**. You want `first-of-type`.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector