# Using nth-of-type to change the style of child elements

Tags: html, css

```css
.indexNewsWidget .col-xs-6 .row-of-4-text-window h3 {
    background: pink;
}

.indexNewsWidget .col-xs-6 .row-of-4-text-window h3:nth-of-type(3), .indexNewsWidget .col-xs-6 .row-of-4-text-window h3:nth-of-type(4) {
    background: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="indexNewsWidget indexNewsWidgetLocal">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
<a>
  <div class="responsiveImage"></div>
  </a>
<div class="row-of-4-text-window">
  <h3>
    <a>text</a>
  </h3>
<p class="hidden-xs">more text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
<a>
  <div class="responsiveImage"></div>
  </a>
<div class="row-of-4-text-window">
  <h3>
    <a>text</a>
  </h3>
<p class="hidden-xs">more text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
<a>
  <div class="responsiveImage"></div>
  </a>
<div class="row-of-4-text-window">
  <h3>
    <a>text</a>
  </h3>
<p class="hidden-xs">more text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
  
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
<a>
  <div class="responsiveImage"></div>
  </a>
<div class="row-of-4-text-window">
  <h3>
    <a>text</a>
  </h3>
<p class="hidden-xs">more text...</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the last two texts to have a background of blue. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but nth-of-type(3) (and 4) and nth-child(3) (and 4) don't seem to do the trick.

What am I doing wrong here? Could someone explain why my solution is not working? I'm pretty sure I've used this many times before

Ta

Comment: You're applying the `nth-child(3)`  or whatever to the `h3` and tehre is only one of these in each div. you need to apply the `nth` to count the super-parent elements *then* style the `h3`

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for,

```
.indexNewsWidget .col-xs-6:nth-of-type(3) .row-of-4-text-window h3, 
.indexNewsWidget .col-xs-6:nth-of-type(4) .row-of-4-text-window h3 {
    background: blue !important;
}
```

Your code is not working, because you are pointing to the 3rd and 4th `<h3>` inside `.row-of-4-text-window` and **not** the `<h3>` inside 3rd and 4th `.col-xs-6`. You may add more `<h3>` in your HTML to see the difference.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad that I could help. You may choose the correct answer so that it will help other users. Thank you.

Comment: sure - was just waiting for the 6 mins left to expire :) all done