# nth-of-type(odd) doesn't work SCSS

Tags: css, sass

EDITED

https://jsfiddle.net/joLav03L/14/

```
td.number:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

Why isn't it working in SCSS?

It worked fine here:

```
  &:nth-of-type(odd) {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

What's the difference? How should i use that?

Comment: remive the `.number` there is a BIG difference between both selector

Comment: You used `<td className="number">` which is not correct.

Comment: i suppose your are using React ?

Comment: Okay, my mistake, i copied it from React, but still. It coloured every td.number, not the odd ones.

Comment: dont use className

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/joLav03L/19/

Try this thing, and You will see the difference

Comment: Yeah, I see the difference. This works only for rows. But how can I use it for columns? I can't change classes, because I'm doing it in a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing little bit wrong. 
like you are telling that every td which has class number in one tr so there is no odd td with class number. so there is only only td with class number in tr.

so you have to select every tr with odd type and then change the color of td in odd tr

```
table {
  width: 800px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  tr {
    display: flex;
    width: 800px;
    th {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 56px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #E5EEFB;
      box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px 0 #FFFFFF;
      border: 1px solid #DAE0E9;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #3A5071;
      letter-spacing: 0.66px;
      text-align: center;
      &:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
      }
      &:last-child {
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
      }
    }
    td {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 56px;
      width: 100%;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      border: 1px solid #DAE0E9;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #577198;
      letter-spacing: 0.75px;
      text-align: center;
      &:nth-of-type(odd) {
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    }
    &:nth-of-type(odd) .number {
        background-color: blue;
      }
  }
}
```

write this code. it will help you

Comment: Oh, that is clear for me now. I was using class wrongly. The best solution.

Comment: @JohnBra Thanks a lot.