# Chrome issue with wordpress posts

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, posts

I have an issue with my site on Chrome. On firefox everything is ok, but when I open my page with chrome I don't see the first post on page, there is a blank space there when it should be, I can see that this post is in the code when I inspect this page. I'm searching for an answer for few days and don't know why is this happening. Anyone had a problem like that? please help me.
I'm loading my posts with wp query from category, im using also a clip path in css (but I tried to comment in and check page and same issue was there).

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">

        <h1 class="home-title text-center">Aktualności</h1>

        <?php 
        $query = new WP_Query( array( 
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'category_name' => 'aktualnosci', 
            'posts_per_page'=> -1 ) ); ?>

        <?php if( $query->have_posts() ) : while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="post-short">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) ); ?>" class="project_pics">

                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                    <h3 class="post-short_title text-center"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                    <?php the_date('d.m.Y', '<p class="text-center post-date">', '</p>'); ?>
                    <div class="excerpt">
                        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


    </div>
</div>
```

This is my code for displaying posts.

and page is szkola.webwitch.pl if anyone can check it

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to be a combination of the clipping, and relative positioning of .post-short - once I remove both, it starts showing up. FYI: `.post-short:nth-of-type(3n+1)` - this probably doesn’t do what you think it does, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/1427878

Comment: this could be something wrong with clip-path on chrome, so i changed it and there is only a color in background without a clip-path...