# First child concept is not working for me?

Tags: html, css

**I am selecting "DATE RANGE" from calendar.I just want additional style for "START DATE " and "END DATE" in that calendar. I have class name of that "SELECTED ROWS" of calendar.but i am trying that first child and last child concept.I don't know why its not working.how to add css for first child and last child in the table td(calendar row)?**

**Before adding first-child**
[image]

**after [image]adding first-child**

Comment: share code not images

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`first-child` and `last-child` do not work like that.

```
<style>
.here:first-child{color:red;}
.there:last-child{color:blue;}
</style>
<ul>
  <li>one
  <li class="here">two
  <li class="there">three
</ul>
```

You might expect second element to be red but it won't. It's because item with class `here` is not first-child (it's second).
Because element with class `there` is also a last child then it will be blue.