# CSS - only of type selector not applying properly

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, styling

I am providing a simplified version of my code. Say this is my .html file:

```
<div>
 <div class="you">Novus ordo seclorum</div>
 <div class="you">Novus ordo seclorum</div>
 <div class="me">I have a buddy below me.</div>
 <div class="me">I have a buddy above me. </div>
 <div class="you"> I am a lonely type. Before and after are all 'me'</div>
 <div class="me">I have a buddy below me.</div>
 <div class="me">I have a buddy above me. </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply a specific .css style to the `class="you"` which is all alone in the middle. There is no element of `class="you"` neither above nor below him.

I tried using the `:only-of-type` selector but it did not apply any styling to the element.

```
.you:only-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

So how do I apply a certain style to an element which has not elements of the same `class` above or below it?

Comment: It should be `.you`, you’re not targeting a `<you>` tag

Comment: I have the `.` in my code. It was a typo when writing the topic.

Comment: There must be something else which is making those differences. Just a sample with your code is https://jsfiddle.net/pzr9mdyk/. Please share your complete code to help you further

Comment: read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector ... the same logic apply here : it works with element and not with classes

Comment: @TemaniAfif, what would be the solution in my case then? Is there no way to achieve this only with plain css?

Comment: since there is no previous selector, I don't think there is a pure CSS solution for this

Comment: by the way you can simply change div with p for the `you` elements

Comment: Yoi could use a id selector  or maybe you-one instead  of only use you also class="you three" then in your css call it as .three, you should share your code to know better if you are unable to use other classes or id values.

Answer (score 0):

Regrettably there is no *immediately previous element* selector in CSS.

What you can do in javascript is identify each `.you` which immediately follows a `.me` (using the `+` selector) and then apply an `.only-you` class to it if it is *also* followed by a `.me`.

**Working Example:**

```js
var meBeforeYous = document.querySelectorAll('.me + .you');

for (var i = 0; i < meBeforeYous.length; i++) {

    if (meBeforeYous[i].nextElementSibling.classList.contains('me')) {
        meBeforeYous[i].classList.add('only-you');
    }       
}
```

```css
.you {
font-weight: bold;
}

.only-you {
color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div class="you">I am a you (with a buddy below).</div>
 <div class="you">I am a you (with a buddy above).</div>
 <div class="me">I have a buddy below me.</div>
 <div class="me">I have a buddy above me. </div>
 <div class="you"> I am a lonely type. Before and after are both 'me'</div>
 <div class="me">I have a buddy below me.</div>
 <div class="me">I have a buddy above me. </div>
 <div class="you">I am a you (with a buddy below).</div>
 <div class="you">I am a you (with a buddy above).</div>
 <div class="me">I have a buddy below me.</div>
 <div class="me">I have a buddy above me. </div>
</div>
```