# combining :nth-child with :not() selectors

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to learn css, but experiencing some problems with it. How can I select every third block, except `invicible` block from counting?

When I using `div.col-12:nth-child(3n+3) {background:blue}` it doesn't work properly, counting invisible block as all other. I've tried to add `:not([id="invisible"])` to it, but it doesn't work at all.

```css
div.col-12:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class=parent>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="invisible"></div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

Comment: Won't fix your problem, but **Note** that you should probably be using `class="invisible"` instead of `id="invisible"` — an `id` must be unique within a page, meaning you can have at most _one_ "invisible" block if you use `id`, where any number of elements can have the same _class_.

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT

### `:nth-of-type` & `:not()`

#### Demo 2

Since OP can't modify HTML (dynamically rendered?) -- we can use the `:not()` selector and a negative starting point for the `:nth-of-type` count. That's the first ruleset below which almost works but the first `.col-12` is blue. So the second ruleset below changes the first `.col-12` back to white. The reason why `:not()` is used again is because the `:not(#invisible)` in the first ruleset has a very high specificity because an id is used -- adding `.col-12` to second ruleset gives higher specificity than the first ruleset.

> ```
> body > div > div:nth-of-type(3n-2):not(#invisible) {
>   background: blue
> }
> body > div > div.col-12:first-of-type:not(#invisible) {
>   background: white 
> }
> ```

---

### `:nth-of-type`

#### Demo 1

Change `#invisible` into anything but a `<div>` then use `:nth-of-type`. `nth-of-type` only considers `tagName`s like `div`, or `section`, so by changing `#invisible` to another tag you will exclude it. Also use the child combinators `>` to "lock" it in. In your layout there's a lot of `<div>`s so this:

> ```
> div:nth-child(3n+3) //The +3 might be a reaction to the unexpected results?
> ```

Will consider ***all*** `<div>`s that are children of anything. This on the other hand:

> ```
> body > div > div:nth-of-type(3n)
> ```

narrows down possibilities. The direct descendant (or child) of `<body>` is `.parent` then only consider the children of `.parent`. Now `.block1` and `.block2` are never considered (it doesn't affect your layout per say because of `3n` but it's best to consider it in the future).

---

## Demo 1

```css
.col-12 {
  outline: 3px dashed red
}

body>div>div:nth-of-type(3n) {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class=parent>

  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <aside id="invisible"></aside>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## Demo 2

```css
.col-12 {
  outline: 3px dashed red
}

body>div>div:nth-of-type(3n-2):not(#invisible) {
  background: blue
}

body>div>div.col-12:first-of-type:not(#invisible) {
  background: white
}
```

```html
<div class=parent>

  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="invisible"></div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <div class="block1">
      <a class="link">link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="block2">
      <p class="text">some text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is obvious and nice solution, but my task is expected not to touch html code, just write a css selector. Is that possible?

Comment: With CSS? Not that I'm aware of. That's the reason why I try to use the tag that's the most semantic, I rarely use `<span>` or `<div>`. To me using `<div>`s and `<span>`s is a code smell. Can you use jQuery/JavaScript?

Comment: @Pavel I think I got it. See answer. Nevermind I forgot to change `#invisible` back to a `<div>`, sorry.

Comment: The closest is: `body > div > div:nth-of-type(3n-2)` but the first `.col-12` is blue.

Comment: it works just with modified "invisible" tag to <aside> (<div> still counting wrong)

Comment: It's still hardcoded - if I add one more "invisible" tag, or just move exciting to another place, it will broke.

Comment: @Pavel maybe you should mention that the list changes then I would've told you there's no solution using CSS alone. You can't have more than one `#invisible` id. ids must be unique. Change it to class `.invisible` but I guess you can't because you can't change the HTML and you can't use jQ/JS (assuming you can't since you didn't answer my previous question concerning jQ/JS).

Comment: Also, you couldn't rely on any CSS if you are changing HTML dynamically because you have a hidden sibling. So the limitations you have of course will limit your possibilities. Another option is to assign a class to every 3rd `.col-12` but again you need to modify HTML or use jQ/JS. Good luck.