# CSS nth-of-type(1) does not select the first element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to set the background color of 3 elements but adressing by number is barely working in my case.

*.bar:nth-of-type(1)* should select the first *bar* element, but it selects nothing. *.bar:nth-of-type(2)* however selects the first *bar* element instead of the second.

> The :nth-of-type() CSS pseudo-class matches elements of a given type,
>   based on their position among a group of siblings.

So I have 3 bar sibling elements, still can't select the first one with 1. What do I miss here?

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="first">some content</div>
    <div class="second">some content</div>
    <div class="barChart">
      <div class="line"></div>
      <div class="bar" style="height:50%;"></div>
      <div class="bar" style="height:30%;"></div>
      <div class="bar" style="height:90%;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 5em;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  background-color: lightGrey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 30%;
}

.second {
  background-color: grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 30%;
}

.barChart {
  background-color: white;
  flex-grow: 2;
  flex-basis: 60%;
}

.barChart {
  background-color: white;
  flex-grow: 2;
   display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
   position: relative;
}

.bar {
    z-index: 10;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background-color:blue;
}

.line{
  z-index: 1;
 border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 width: 100%;
 position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
}

.bar:nth-of-type(1){
  background-color: red;
}
```

The following stackoverflow question does not not provide an answer on why this happens: [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

Comment: from the duplicate : *The :nth-child() pseudo-class counts elements among all of their siblings under the same parent. It does not count only the siblings that match the rest of the selector. Similarly, the :nth-of-type() pseudo-class counts siblings sharing the same element type, which refers to the tag name in HTML, and not the rest of the selector.* --> note the : **It does not count only the siblings that match the rest of the selector**

Comment: @TemaniAfif I understand that nth child counts all the child elements.
But I'm using nth-of-type which does not count in non matching elements. Hence it should change the background color of the first bar element.

 _This number represents the element's position within only those of its siblings that are of the same element type._
OR https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

It looks like nth-of-type works perfectly  on elements(div,li,p...) but not with class based selectors.

Comment: please read all the comment. it's about nth-child and nth-of-type --> *Similarly, the :nth-of-type() pseudo-class counts siblings sharing the same element type, which refers to the tag name in HTML, and not the rest of the selector.* --> **not the rest of the selector**