# CSS general sibling and nth-of-type selector - odd behavior?

Tags: html, css

Consider this snippet:

```css
.test input.one ~ div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

.test input.two ~ div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form class="test">
  <input class="one" />
  <div></div>
  <input class="two" />
  <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
  <div style="height: 50px;"></div>
</form>
```

What I would expect to happen is that the first `<div style="height: 50px;"></div>` would be red, and the second one would be blue. Instead, the `nth-of-type(2)` selector is selecting the first `<div style="height: 50px;"></div>` both times.

I thought that `.test input.two ~ div:nth-of-type(2)` would start at `<input class="two" />`, and count downwards 2 `<div>` tags, and land on the second one?

What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`nth-of-type()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) "matches elements of a given type, based on their position among a group of siblings". Your code is selecting the `<div>` that is preceded by `input.two` *and is also* the second `<div>` sibling in the parent element.

In your case, you might consider using the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator). Below, I'm selecting the `<div>` that immediately follows `.one` (red) and the `<div>` that immediately follows the `<div>` that immediately follows `.two` (blue).

```css
.one + div {
  background-color: red;
}

.two + div + div {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form class="test">
  <input class="one" value="one">
  <div>A</div>
  <input class="two" value="two">
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</form>
```

---

Just for fun, here's an example to help visualize `nth-of-type` by grouping elements in separate parent containers.

```css
.one ~ div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.two ~ div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<form class="test">
  <div>
    <input class="one" value="one">
    <div>A</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input class="two" value="two">
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, even though I'm using ... `~ div:nth-of-type(2)` inside of the parent ... it's still going to select the second div relative to the parent as a whole?

Comment: Yes, that's right. I often wish there was something like [nth-of-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)!

Comment: Darn. I figured combining these two would make the nth count start from a sibling. Appreciate the workaround example!