# Add for each second li with active class, different background

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to add different background for each second active class that list with `<li>` has
The code below displays different `div`on click function. 
The `active` class I have added with jQuery, and after that I'm trying to add different background for divs 2, 4, 6 ....

I tried with css, but doesn't work for me:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.results > li').hide();

  $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    $('.results > li').hide();
    $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function() {
      $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
    });
  });
  if (!$('.results > li').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('.results > li').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
ul.results li.nth-child(even) .active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="arts" />
            Arts
        </label>
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="computers" />
            Computers
        </label>
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="health" />
            Health
        </label>
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" />
            Video Games
        </label>
</div>
<ul class="results">
  <li class="arts computers">Result 1</li>
  <li class="video-games">Result 2</li>
  <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3</li>
  <li class="arts video-games">Result 4</li>
</ul>
```

Example: If check-boxes  Art andh Health are checked, they will display Result1, Result 3 Result 4. In this case, Result 3 should be with background red.
https://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/Ddnuh/

Comment: You must be using  a very old version of jQuery. `live()` has been deprecated since 2011

Comment: @charlietfl  I have replaced with `on`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there is a problem in your CSS. `nth-child` is a pseudo selector and not a class. Also, it [doesn't work in conjunction with classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector).

You need to use JavaScript to accomplish this. I'm sure the code can be optimised, but I'm leaving that upto you to figure out. These are the steps that I'm following:

1. Reset the state of all the `li`s on every checkbox click
2. Add a class called `active` to all visible `li`s
3. Add a `highlight` class to all even numbered `active` `li`s. The code uses [`:odd`](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) because this custom jQuery selector is 0-indexed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.results > li').hide();

  $('div.tags').find('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    $('.results > li').hide().removeClass('highlight active');

    $('div.tags').find('input:checked').each(function() {
      $('.results > li.' + $(this).attr('rel')).show().addClass('active');
    });

    $('.active:odd').addClass('highlight')
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tags">
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="arts" />
            Arts
        </label>
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="computers" />
            Computers
        </label>
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="health" />
            Health
        </label>
  <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" />
            Video Games
        </label>
</div>
<ul class="results">
  <li class="arts computers">Result 1</li>
  <li class="video-games">Result 2</li>
  <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3</li>
  <li class="arts video-games">Result 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem in your code is `li.nth-child(even)` `nth-child` is used with `pseudo operator` so use `:` not `.`

try this

```css
li:nth-child(even){
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="arts" />
            Arts
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="computers" />
            Computers
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="health" />
            Health
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" rel="video-games" />
            Video Games
        </label>
    </div>
 <ul class="results">
        <li class="arts computers">Result 1</li>
        <li class="video-games">Result 2</li>
        <li class="computers health video-games">Result 3</li>
        <li class="arts video-games">Result 4</li>
    </ul>
```

its working

Comment: but what happens if Ars and Health Checkboxes are checked, with Result 1 and Result 4?
 In this case Result 4 should have red background.

Comment: what do you mean? I didn't understand! `LI` will be toggle on click checkbox?

Comment: this will work if the `result 1` and `result 4` will show then only `result 4` will have red background

Comment: if you want to bind `CSS` properties with `JS` function toggle, this will not work, Because of `CSS` with make impact when the document is ready and `dom` is `rendering` first time on Browser window, If you want to toggle `CSS` with `JS` function, then please use add remove CSS properties in JS code