# Apply style to all matches of a css selector but the last match with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

For instance if I have the following:

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    [...]
</div>
```

I'd like to apply a CSS like this one:

```css
.content .item {
    display: none;
}
```

Except that I want the last item (in this case the 4th item) to be displayed. I don't want the style to be applied to it - or to be able to apply display: block to the last item after applying display:none to all of them. Since there are other blocks inside the div.content I can't reliably use the `:last-child` of `last-of-type` pseudo-functions.

I though of using prototype selection via javascript to get all the items and add a particular class like "last-item" or just straight set the style there doing something like this:

```
$$('.content .item').forEach(function(item) {
    item.setStyle('display: none')
})
$$('.content .item').last().setStyle('display: block')
```

I sort of rather if there was a way I could get the same result using CSS in a more clever way. So that's the question: can I pull that off?

Comment: Could you please give an example of what else is in the `content` div as from your question it is still unclear why you "can't reliably use the :last-child of :last-of-type pseudo-functions"

Comment: I imagine that these _"other blocks"_ are also `<div>` elements which is why you cannot use `:last-of-type`

Comment: Basically you want the [`nth-child( of )`](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-nth-child-pseudo) which is IIRC still not supported by anyone... [There are \[css\] dupes though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector). But I now see you are willing a js solution.

Comment: @Kaiido OP **is** using JS to solve this but their question appears to be asking if there's a CSS-only way to do the same thing. To that, the answer is still _"no"_