# Create floating elements with css rule on odd elements and display none / block in HTML / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-float

I am doing a program with a list of elements (float or flex) that might have a display of "none", that can change dynamically. I manage to do it in CSS when it is defined with a selector :

```
div:nth-child(odd)
```

However if I hide one div, it doesn't work anymore. I tried something like

```
div[style*="display: block;"]:nth-child(odd)
```

but breaks.

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
 
.flex-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ddd;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}

.flex-container>div[style*="display: block;"]:nth-child(odd) {
  border-right: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="flex1" style="display: block;">TEST 1</div>
  <div id="flex2" style="display: block;">TEST 2</div>
  <div id="flex3" style="display: block;">TEST 3</div>
  <div id="flex4" style="display: block;">TEST 4</div>
  <div id="flex5" style="display: block;">TEST 5</div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('flex1').style.display = document.getElementById('flex1').style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'" value="Flex1" />
```

When using the button, it shows / hides the first div. What I would like is to have this red border always in the middle.

I would like to avoid using javascript as much as possible.

Maybe I got it completely wrong, or it isn't feasible without javascript.

Comment: You mean to say if you click odd div's it should hide correct ?

Comment: No, what I want is: within the div displayed only the the odd one have a border-right. my button is just to hide/show the first div and to illustrate my need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to complicate with `nth-child`. You can simply draw a line in the middle using pseudo element. Also read the following to understand why your code doesn't work: [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/8620333)

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
 
.flex-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ddd;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position:relative;
}
.flex-container:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:50%;
  width:1px;
  background:red;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="flex1" style="display: block;">TEST 1</div>
  <div id="flex2" style="display: block;">TEST 2</div>
  <div id="flex3" style="display: block;">TEST 3</div>
  <div id="flex4" style="display: block;">TEST 4</div>
  <div id="flex5" style="display: block;">TEST 5</div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('flex1').style.display = document.getElementById('flex1').style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'" value="Flex1" />
```

Here is another idea using CSS grid:

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
 
.flex-container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 5px auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap:1px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red,red) center/1px 100% no-repeat,
    #ddd;
}

.flex-container>div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div id="flex1" style="display: block;">TEST 1</div>
  <div id="flex2" style="display: block;">TEST 2</div>
  <div id="flex3" style="display: block;">TEST 3</div>
  <div id="flex4" style="display: block;">TEST 4</div>
  <div id="flex5" style="display: block;">TEST 5</div>
</div>

<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('flex1').style.display = document.getElementById('flex1').style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none'" value="Flex1" />
```