# Problem with nth-child - it does count all divs instead of divs of certain class

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to select every fourth element and apply 0 margin to it.

I have this:

```
.products .item:not(.inactive):nth-child(4n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

I want to select every 4th element of type `div.item` but not `.inactive`

There I have two problems:

**Problem 1**

If I add any `div` element (even if it's not of type `.item`) then it includes it in counting eg.

```
<div class="products">
<div class="anything"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div> // <- this is where the margin-right: 0 happens
<div class="item"></div> // <- it should happen here
</div>
```

**Problem 2**

If I add `.inactive` class (using jquery) (which basically hides the `.inactive` element), the counting as above still happens - so all items within `.products` `div` are taken into account and `margin-right: 0` is applied to fourth element regardless it's `item`, `item inactive`, `anything` etc.

Comment: The selector is `:nth-child` not `:nth-of-class`. It will ignore classes.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1:** [Using `nth-child` with arbitary selectors doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

**Problem 2:** This is the same reason as the first one; but being as you mentioned that you were using jQuery to add the `inactive` class, you can use jQuery to solve your `nth-child` issue, by instead using [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```js
$('.products').find('.item:not(.inactive)').eq(3) // Array like, so starts at 0
  .css('margin-right', '0')
  .css('background-color', 'red'); // Just for demo
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="products">
  <div class="anything">a</div>
  <div class="anything">b</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>  <!-- this is where the margin-right: 0 happens -->
  <div class="item">4</div>  <!-- it should happen here </div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Light I wasn't aware of full implications of `:nth-child`. However I need to select every 3rd child, not only third child so `eq(3)` won't work in my case - I did use different script to change the styling in this case.

Comment: No worries; Glad I could help with something if not the whole question - I did think if you might needed every third.. Ah well