# How to select the last of the class

Tags: html, css

I would like to select the last one from li.selected
but the utopian selector

```
.selected:last-of-type {
  background: hotpink;
}
```

doesn't work at all.

```
<ul>
  <li class="selected">un</li>
  <li class="selected">deux</li>
  <li class="selected"> ---- I want select that one ----- </li>
  <li class="foo">quatre</li>
  <li>cinq</li>
  <li class="tang">six</li>
</ul>
```

I cannot use the following selector

```
.selected:nth-child(3) {
  background: hotpink;
}
```

because it's for a dynamic application so,
How can I proceed only with css selectors?

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Salaun, Kindly accept the answer if you think worth accepting it!

Comment: post who can be usefull: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Source: [last](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_lastchild.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".selected:last").css("background-color", "yellow");
 });
```

[image]

**OR**

another way of using it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $( ".selected" ).last().css({ backgroundColor: "yellow", fontWeight: 
  "bolder" });
});
```

[image]

**UPDATE-1**

here is why the `utopian-selector` will not work in you case.

check this example:

```css
.selected:last-of-type {
  background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="selected">un</li>
  <li class="selected">deux</li>
  <li class="selected"> ---- I want select that one ----- </li>
</ul>
```

if you observe the example, if you remove the remaining `list(li)` post `selected` class, it works by your way.

**why it is not working**

> `:last-of-type` It targets a particular type of element in a particular arrangement with relation to similar siblings, not all siblings.

so, since there were **other** siblings apart from `selected` in your list hence it was not able to pick that color because it didn't find the element of `selected` class at the end, hope it make sense now.

Comment: Hi, I expected an css solution but, like that you let me know that its not possible by that way or my logic should be changed. Thanks to you !

Comment: @CédricSalaün I got your concern, I have just updated a small snippet with explanation that will clear the air why it was not working before using ':last-of-type`. let me know.

Comment: @CédricSalaün the one you accepted it as answer, still uses `last` as property to fill the color, which is what my code does in the first snippet. I also explained the reason why it won't work in your case, it is your call anyway! thanks.

Comment: I think it is like @pakman198 said so,
the `last-of-type` selector is not working is because it only works for html elements, no class selector. By consequences `.selected:last-of-type` looking for the `:last-of-type` with `.selected` class, and it make sens why nothing happened

Comment: Great! that you understood the concept! I am glad.

Comment: Sorry @Manjuboyz I'm brand new stack overflow user, I was looking for a similar topic before post but in vain and now I  see lots of similar posts.

Comment: Welcome to SO, we all learn everyday don't worry and no need to be sorry as well! happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure, but I think you are trying to do something like this:

```css
ul li:nth-last-of-type(1){background:red}
ul li:nth-last-of-type(3){background:blue}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="selected">un</li>
  <li class="selected">deux</li>
  <li class="selected"> ---- I want select that one ----- </li>
  <li class="foo">quatre</li>
  <li>cinq</li>
  <li class="tang">six</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** For using nth-child or nth-last-of-type, you will have to make selection of element, for classes it won't work.

If you are trying to name the item and then count it from top or bottom, this won't work in CSS as per now.

Either you will have to use jQuery or some JavaScript library (for dynamic counting) or else you will have to point out element (somehow using CSS Selectors) and then make CSS changes.

**Note:** Current CSS3 specification does not provide selecting classes based on counting. So, if you are trying to count classes and use either of `nth-child, nth-last-child, nth-of-type, nth-last-of-type` you will be highly dissapointed as they will couunt based on Elements, for example `ul li` but will not take into consideration of class while counting, for example `ul li.selected:nth-child(3)`. So, this will be rendered unuseful in your case.

**Using jQuery:**

You got 2 options - a) `:last` b) `.last()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.selected:last').css('background', 'red')
  $( '.selected' ).last().css( "color", "blue" );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <ul>
      <li class="selected">un</li>
      <li class="selected">deux</li>
      <li class="selected"> ---- I want select that one ----- </li>
      <li class="foo">quatre</li>
      <li>cinq</li>
      <li class="tang">six</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks you, its actually in angular2+ context so i wont use jQuery for that


`code`@ViewChildren('startDaysCalendar', { read: ElementRef }) public readonly startDaysCalendar: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLElement>>;
this.startDaysCalendar.toArray().forEach((elem: ElementRef<HTMLElement>, index: number) => ((index === 3) { this._renderer.addClass(elem.nativeElement, 'last); }
));

(Sorry, I'm having some troubles to formatting.comment)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the ability to use nth on a class-name:

In this snippet '.selected' is a class name. You must instead use the DOM element.

```
ul .selected:nth-of-type(3) {
    color: red;
}
```

you can only use this on DOM elements so you would want to use:

```
ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
    color: red;
}
```

I can appreciate this is a very simple answer, if you require further help creating a selector when you actually come to writing this into your site, let me know.

Comment: Nope, OP needs the value to be dynamic not the 3rd child!

Comment: Use a JS solution. You have already highlighted how to do this nicely. This is why I noted if he requires more help with the code he is actually using, I would help him further.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
const selected = document.querySelectorAll('.selected');
const last = selected[selected.length-1];
last.classList.add('last');
```

Then update your css

```css
.selected.last {
  background: hotpink;
}
```

The reason why the `last-of-type` selector is not working is because it only works for html elements, no class selectors :(

I guess you're sort of adding that .selected class given some rules, so when you add the selected class, you can also validate if it's the last element and add a class like `.last`

Probably, your best option would be to use javascript or add a second class to that .selected element.