# In CSS, is 'div:first-of-type[label="hello"]' different from 'div[label="hello"]:first-of-type'?

Tags: css, syntax, css-selectors, match, operator-precedence

In CSS, is this selector:

`div:first-of-type[label="hello"]`

any different from:

`div[label="hello"]:first-of-type`

?

Comment: nop. Same as `.foo.bar` is same as `.bar.foo`. It's only difference in performance, but difference is way too little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike pseudo element, pseudo classes can appear in the middle of a selector:

> Pseudo-classes are allowed in all sequences of simple selectors contained in a selector. Pseudo-classes **are allowed anywhere in sequences of simple selectors**, after the leading type selector or universal selector (possibly omitted). <sup>[ref](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#pseudo-classes)</sup>

So both are the same

```css
div[label="hello"]:first-of-type {
  height:50px;
}


div:first-of-type[label="hello"] {
  border:5px solid;
}
```

```html
<div label="hello" class="box"></div>
```

---

Considering [the new specification](http://w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#pseudo-classes):

> Like other simple selectors, pseudo-classes are allowed in all compound selectors contained in a selector, and must follow the type selector or universal selector, if present.

---

Worth to note that `:first-of-type` will only consider the element and its sibling. So the first selector will not select the first div having `label=hello` but the first div if it has the `label=hello`.

In other words, the 2 conditions must be true to select the element that's why the order doesn't matter and both selectors are the same.

You can see both selectors like below:

```
div[label="hello"]:first-of-type
(div) && (label="hello") && (first of type)
(div) && (first of type) && (label="hello")
div:first-of-type[label="hello"]
```

Related: [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/8620333)

Comment: Thank you Temani.  I find it interesting because in English, the meaning is very different (the first "hello" label vs. any first div that is labelled "hello").  But thanks to your answer, it's clear that CSS does not follow English semantics in this situation.

Comment: I have read your first edit a few times, and find it confusing. Is it saying things are staying the same way in CSS4 (as CSS3) or changing?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard this is a common, mistake with such selectors, added more details to avoid this confusing

Comment: Uh oh. I just read your second edit ("Worth to note...") and now it is sounding like they are different.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard it's the same thing but said differently. Both means that you can have any order and the selector will remain the same

Comment: @RockPaperLizard edited again :) they are still the same

Comment: Thanks.  Your fourth edit clears it up!  Thank you!