# Apply common css to alternate class

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a nested table. I am applying common color to alternate rows. To avoid color scheme getting messed up due to sub tables I have applied a class as "view" to all the parent rows and to every odd row I am applying green. But for some reason it is also applying the css to the second row !

```
<table class="table fold-table parent" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Contact Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="view">

      <td>John</td>
      <td>j@g</td>
      <td>35373726</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
      <td colspan="3">
        <div class="fold-content">

          <table class="child">

            <tbody>
              <tr >

               <td >SUB one</td>
                <td >SUB two</td>
                <td >SUB three</td>
         
              </tr>
              <tr >

               <td >SUB one</td>
                <td >SUB two</td>
                <td >SUB three</td>
              </tr>
              <tr >

                <td >SUB one</td>
                <td >SUB two</td>
                <td >SUB three</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view">
      
       <td>John</td>
      <td>j@g</td>
      <td>35373726</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view">
      
       
      <td >Sh. Nima Dawa Bhutia</td>
      <td >Adl. PS to minister</td>
      <td >547383</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view">
      
       
      <td >Sh. Nima Dawa Bhutia</td>
      <td >Adl. PS to minister</td>
      <td >547383</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

```
table.parent{
 
  font-size:12px;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 2px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  
}

table thead th{
  
  border-bottom:0;
  border-top:0;
}

table td,th{
  border-top: 0px;
}

 table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view td, table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view.open {
  background:  #ddd;
}

 table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold {
  display: none;
}
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold.open {
  display: table-row;
 
} 

.view:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: green;
}

table.child:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color:red;
}

table.fold-content > tr{
  background-color:#ddd !important;
  
}

table.child{
  
  
  font-size:12px;
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0 2px;
  width: 100%;
  
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold.open > td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```
$(function(){
    $(".fold-table tr.view").on("click", function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("open").next(".fold").toggleClass("open");
    });
  });
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

Comment: The problem is n-child will pick the nested row as well. Is there a way to just pick the element having odd index? Like all the "view" classes at odd index?

Comment: _“Is there a way to just pick the element having odd index? Like all the "view" classes at odd index?”_ - what do you think I mentioned this duplicate for? It explicitly states that what you are (re-)asking for right now, is _not possible_.

Comment: If you have control over the HTML and it's not a dynamic table (rows added/removed as required) then just apply a different css on odd/over rows directly to the HTML (`.view.odd { color: green }`) - how you generate the HTML will lead to how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But for some reason it is also applying the css to the second row !

It isn't - it's applying the css to *the third row*.

The second row is `tr.fold` so it has `display: none` applied to it.

It's true that appears to be the second row is green - but that *isn't* the second row, it's the third.

What you need is to apply the green background to every alternate  `tr.view` row.

You can achieve this by cycling through only the  `tr.view` rows and alternately applying `data-odd-row="true"` or `data-odd-row="false"`, like this:

```
let oddRow = true;

for (visibleTableRow of visibleTableRows) {

  visibleTableRow.setAttribute('data-odd-row', oddRow);
  oddRow = (oddRow === true) ? false : true;
}
```

**Working Example:**

```js
let oddRow = true;
let visibleTableRows = [...document.querySelectorAll('#table  tbody > tr.view')];

for (visibleTableRow of visibleTableRows) {

  visibleTableRow.setAttribute('data-odd-row', oddRow);
  oddRow = (oddRow === true) ? false : true;
}
```

```css
table.parent{
 
  font-size:12px;
  width: 50%;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 2px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  
}

table thead th{
  
  border-bottom:0;
  border-top:0;
}

table td,th{
  border-top: 0px;
}

 table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view td, table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view th {
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view:hover {
  background: #ddd;
}
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.view.open {
  background:  #ddd;
}

 table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold {
  display: none;
}
table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold.open {
  display: table-row;
 
} 

tr.view[data-odd-row="true"]
{
    background-color: green;
}

table.child:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color:red;
}

table.fold-content > tr{
  background-color:#ddd;
  
}

table.child{
  
  
  font-size:12px;
  border: none;
  border-spacing: 0 2px;
  width: 100%;
  
}

table.fold-table > tbody > tr.fold.open > td {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table fold-table parent" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Contact Details</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="view">

      <td>John</td>
      <td>j@g</td>
      <td>35373726</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="fold">
      <td colspan="3">
        <div class="fold-content">

          <table class="child">

            <tbody>
              <tr >

               <td >SUB one</td>
                <td >SUB two</td>
                <td >SUB three</td>
         
              </tr>
              <tr >

               <td >SUB one</td>
                <td >SUB two</td>
                <td >SUB three</td>
              </tr>
              <tr >

                <td >SUB one</td>
                <td >SUB two</td>
                <td >SUB three</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view">
      
       <td>John</td>
      <td>j@g</td>
      <td>35373726</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view">
      
       
      <td >Sh. Nima Dawa Bhutia</td>
      <td >Adl. PS to minister</td>
      <td >547383</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="view">
      
       
      <td >Sh. Nima Dawa Bhutia</td>
      <td >Adl. PS to minister</td>
      <td >547383</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes. I meant second row in non-expanded view of the table (which actually is third). I was trying by using tr.view:nth-child(odd){ } but it seems nth-child doesn't like that. So, i tried manipulation it with JS and it worked. I tried your solution just now and it works, too. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Happy to help, @ItikaBandta. Note that the `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` pseudo-classes pay no attention to classes or ids. They only look at HTML structure.