# Submenus with different styling Css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, submenu

I'm stuck.
I want to change the background in submenu-third through `:nth-child`. Because I want that the only first 2 block(`:nth-child(-n+2)`) have `background:blue`, but I become that all `.submenu-third` have background:blue.

How do I add styles for only the first two blocks?

```
<nav>
                <ul class="topmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="active">home</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 2</a>
                                
                                <ul class="submenu-third">
                                    <li><a href=""> 1 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""> 2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""> 3 </a></li>
                                </ul>

                                
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 4</a></li>

                            <li><a href="">menu second level 5</a>
                                <ul class="submenu-third">
                                    <li><a href=""> 5 third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""> 5 third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""> 5 third level</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li><a href="">menu second level 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 7</a></li>

                            <li><a href="">menu second level 8</a>
                                <ul class="submenu-third">
                                    <li><a href="">8menu the third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">8menu the third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">8menu the third level</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 10</a>
                                <ul class="submenu-third">
                                    <li><a href="">10menu the third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">10menu the third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">10menu the third level</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">company</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

```
.submenu-third:nth-child(-n+2){background: blue;}
.submenu li a:nth-child(2n){color: red;}
```

Comment: Do you want to add another class to your first ul? so its easier to target it with css !?

Comment: @hamid, I need to do this in general. Perhaps the client will change the menu, according to the behavior it schould not change. (background - is only the example)

Comment: you can add class to the first Element using javascript and asign css style to it. do you want me to write the (simple) code?

Comment: You seem to not have understood what an actual _child_ in terms of DOM is yet. **All** of your `.submenu-third` elements in the shown HTML are the _second_ child of their parent LI.

Comment: @CBroe I tried this with .submenu-third:nth-of-type(1) and it didn't work either.

Comment: You can not combine these selectors with class selectors, see explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Comment: You can select the `li` based on which child of the `ul.submenu` _they_ are here first, and then format the `.submenu-third` contained in that `li`.

Answer (score 0):

you can add class to the first Element using javascript and asign css style to it.

```js
document.querySelector(".submenu-third").classList.add("secondClass");
```

```css
.secondClass li:nth-of-type(-n+2){background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<nav>
                <ul class="topmenu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="active">home</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 2</a>
                                
                                <ul class="submenu-third">
                                    <li><a href=""> 1 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""> 2 </a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""> 3 </a></li>
                                </ul>

                                
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 3</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 4</a></li>

                            <li><a href="">menu second level 5</a>
                                <ul class="submenu-third">
                                    <li><a href=""> 5 third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""> 5 third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href=""> 5 third level</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li><a href="">menu second level 6</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 7</a></li>

                            <li><a href="">menu second level 8</a>
                                <ul class="submenu-third">
                                    <li><a href="">8menu the third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">8menu the third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">8menu the third level</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 9</a></li>
                            <li><a href="">menu second level 10</a>
                                <ul class="submenu-third">
                                    <li><a href="">10menu the third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">10menu the third level</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="">10menu the third level</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="">company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">company</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```