# How to select second element of nth-of-type(2) in pupeeteer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors, puppeteer, react-testing-library

Consider it like this

```
div[class='myclass']:nth-of-type(2)
```

Now there are 2 elements of this type. How can I select the second element in it. Or any nth element.

Comment: So you basically want to select the second element child of `div[class='myclass']:nth-of-type(2)`?

Comment: suppose there are 2 elements whose second child has class name  = "myclass", now I want to select second one among them

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

Comment: doesn't seems so