# Is there a way to select the first/last non-hidden element using CSS3?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to style form fieldsets with a margin, but remove margin-top for the first non-hidden fieldset and margin-bottom for the last non-hidden fieldset (any fieldset may be set hidden by the script dynamically). I tried the following CSS with no luck (fs2 is expected to have no margin-top but actually has; fs3 is expected to have no margin-bottom but actually has). Is there a way to do something like this using CSS3?

```css
form > fieldset {
  margin: .5em;
}

/* this doesn't work */
form > fieldset:not([hidden]):first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/* this doesn't work */
form > fieldset:not([hidden]):last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset hidden>fs1</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs2</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs3</fieldset>
  <fieldset hidden>fs4</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you intend for border collapse to be enabled?

Comment: You mean margin collapse? I did have it in mind but want a general solution of such case without having to count on margin collapse.

Comment: There isn't a selector-based solution for the last such element. A robust solution for the first such element involves multiple selectors and multiple CSS rules, and isn't even completely foolproof without taking advantage of margin collapsing. This is supposed to be addressed with fieldset:nth-child(1 of :not([hidden])) and fieldset:nth-last-child(1 of :not([hidden])) which still isn't widely supported.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Comment: The :last-of-type pseudo-class looks for the last element of its type *and also* for that element to be not hidden based on your selector. Your last `fieldset` element is hidden, so nothing will apply. Selectors are all-or-nothing, not any-of-the-above.

Comment: What is it that you want to accomplish? Why only the first visible element? What if there are multiple non-contiguous visible elements in this list?

Comment: @TylerH: It's not uncommon to want to remove the topmost and bottommost margins from a series of elements, and it's not uncommon to accomplish that by targeting the first and last visible elements. It's in a similar vein to applying rounded corners to the first and last visible elements in a series.

Comment: @BoltClock I guess I was thinking there would be more items after the ones selected, but that doesn't make sense after shaking my head a bit and thinking about it a second time. It seems like it would be better to just remove unwanted elements rather than applying an attribute to them. That way `:first-of-type` and `:last-of-type` would work.

Comment: @TylerH Hiding doesn't always mean unwanted. Elements hidden by the script may be unhidden sometimes, and that's why removing is not necessarily better than hiding.

Comment: @DannyLin You can insert elements into an array while they're not needed, since you're already using JS. Like airplanes in a holding pattern at an airport.

Answer (score 2):

`gap` was created for such use case

```css
form {
  display:grid;
  gap:0.5em;
  border:1px solid red;
  margin:10px;
}
fieldset {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset hidden>fs1</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs2</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs3</fieldset>
  <fieldset hidden>fs4</fieldset>
</form>


<form>
  <fieldset hidden>fs1</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs2</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs3</fieldset>
  <fieldset >fs4</fieldset>
</form>

<form>
  <fieldset hidden>fs1</fieldset>
  <fieldset hidden>fs2</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs3</fieldset>
  <fieldset >fs4</fieldset>
</form>

<form>
  <fieldset hidden>fs1</fieldset>
  <fieldset hidden>fs2</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs3</fieldset>
  <fieldset hidden>fs4</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately browser support is awful.

Comment: @DannyLin euh, are you sure? ... Even IE support CSS grid: https://caniuse.com/css-grid ... CSS grid is not something new, it has been around since too long now

Comment: @TermaniAfif Support for grid is difinitely not support for gap. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap), IE does not support the `gap` property.

Comment: @DannyLin and this is what you call *awful*? IE not supporting something? ... IE (the dead browser) doesn't support *anything* useful.

Comment: @TermaniAfif Though it may be context dependent, my apps usually target Fx >= 52 and Chromium >= 55 (the first version with JS async/await), and both do not support it. This is certainly newer than many other techniques I am using.

Comment: @DannyLin use the old syntax `grid-row-gap`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), `+` to do this with:

```
form > fieldset[hidden] + fieldset {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

This will set the first sibling of the hidden fieldset to have no top margin:

```css
form > fieldset {
  margin: .5em;
}

/* this doesn't work */
form > fieldset[hidden] + fieldset {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset hidden>fs1</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs2</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs3</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: This will be buggy if I have hidden fs1, non-hidden fs2, hidden fs3, and non-hidden fs4. In such case fs4 will be unexpectedly have margin-top removed.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the rest of your page styles are written, a common technique is to just apply margin to the bottom of your elements.

```css
/* Remove top margin */
margin: 0 0.5em 0.5em;
```

But since it looks like you want to remove all vertical margin it may be easier to apply a negative margin to the top and bottom of the form?

```css
form > fieldset {
  margin: .5em;
}
form {
  margin: -0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<span>Lorem</span>
<form>
  <fieldset hidden>fs1</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs2</fieldset>
  <fieldset>fs3</fieldset>
  <fieldset hidden>fs4</fieldset>
</form>
<span>Ipsum</span>
```

Answer (score -3):

As @j08691 answered, the adjacent sibling selector (`+`), maybe do the trick.
You can also use with the `first-of-type` selector to affect only the first occurence.

```
form > fieldset[hidden]:first-of-type + fieldset
```

Comment: This will be buggy if I have hidden fs1, hidden fs2, and non-hidden fs3. In such case fs3 will be unexpectedly have margin-top preserved.

Comment: :first-of-type will always choose the first fieldset. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class