# Form field border-radius is not working only on the last element

Tags: html, css

I would like the last field to have 50px border radius on the right. Why is this not working?

```css
/*
 * Search
 */
#top {
  max-width: 1182px;
}

#top .search-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#top .search-wrapper .text {
  margin-right: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#top .form-search {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#top .form-search .form-group {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

#top .form-search .form-group:last-child {
  max-width: 130px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#top .form-search select,
#top .form-search input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  background-image: initial;
  color: #515151;
}

#top .form-search select:focus,
#top .form-search select:active,
#top .form-search input:focus,
#top .form-search input:active {
  border-color: #aaaaaa;
}

#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:first-child select,
#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:first-child input {
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}

#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:last-child select,
#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:last-child input {
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}

#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:not(:last-child) select,
#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:not(:last-child) input {
  border-right: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
}

#top .form-search img.search-triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 15px;
}

#top .form-search .btn-submit {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: right;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f5af18;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f5af18;
  color: white;
}

#top .form-search .btn-submit:focus,
#top .form-search .btn-submit:active {
  outline: 0;
}

#top .form-search .btn-submit[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#top .load-more-posts img,
#top .form-search .btn-submit img {
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

#top .form-search .btn-submit .btn-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="text">Search position by</div>

    <form class="form-search" data-post_type="guilds">
      <div class="form-group bordered">
        <label for="keyword" class="sr-only">Keyword</label>

        <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Keyword" tabindex="1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group bordered">
        <label for="professional-types" class="sr-only">Professional type</label>

        <select name="professional-types" id="professional-types" tabindex="2">
          <option value="">Professional type</option>
          <option value="425">3D Developer</option>
          <option value="395">3D modeling specialist</option>
          <option value="404">3D Project Manager</option>
          <option value="420">3D Specialist</option>
          <option value="402">3D Technical Designer</option>
          <option value="416">CAD Designer</option>
          <option value="391">Fashion designer</option>
          <option value="393">Graphic designer</option>
          <option value="392">Pattern maker</option>
          <option value="408">Product Developer</option>
          <option value="422">Rendering Specialist</option>
          <option value="413">technical developer</option>
        </select>

        <img src="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/search-triangle.svg" class="search-triangle" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group bordered">
        <label for="employment-types" class="sr-only">Employment type</label>

        <select name="employment-types" id="employment-types" tabindex="3">
          <option value="">Employment type</option>
          <option value="389">Freelance</option>
          <option value="387">Full time</option>
          <option value="419">Internship</option>
          <option value="390">None</option>
          <option value="388">Part time</option>
        </select>

        <img src="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/search-triangle.svg" class="search-triangle" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group bordered">
        <label for="locations" class="sr-only">Location</label>

        <select name="locations" id="locations" tabindex="4">
          <option value="">Location</option>
          <option value="129">Afghanistan</option>
          <option value="130">Åland Islands</option>
          <option value="131">Albania</option>
          <option value="132">Algeria</option>
          <option value="133">American Samoa</option>
          <option value="134">Andorra</option>
          <option value="135">Angola</option>
          <option value="136">Anguilla</option>
          <option value="137">Antarctica</option>
          <option value="138">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
          <option value="139">Argentina</option>
          <option value="140">Armenia</option>
          <option value="141">Aruba</option>
          <option value="142">Australia</option>
          <option value="143">Austria</option>
          <option value="144">Azerbaijan</option>
          <option value="145">Bahamas</option>
          <option value="146">Bahrain</option>
          <option value="147">Bangladesh</option>
          <option value="148">Barbados</option>
          <option value="149">Belarus</option>
          <option value="150">Belgium</option>
          <option value="151">Belize</option>
          <option value="152">Benin</option>
          <option value="153">Bermuda</option>
          <option value="154">Bhutan</option>
          <option value="155">Bolivia</option>
          <option value="156">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
          <option value="414">Boston</option>
          <option value="157">Botswana</option>
          <option value="158">Bouvet Island</option>
          <option value="159">Brazil</option>
          <option value="160">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
          <option value="161">British Virgin Islands</option>
          <option value="162">Brunei</option>
          <option value="163">Bulgaria</option>
          <option value="164">Burkina Faso</option>
          <option value="165">Burundi</option>
          <option value="409">California</option>
          <option value="166">Cambodia</option>
          <option value="167">Cameroon</option>
          <option value="168">Canada</option>
          <option value="169">Cape Verde</option>
          <option value="170">Caribbean Netherlands</option>
          <option value="171">Cayman Islands</option>
          <option value="172">Central African Republic</option>
          <option value="173">Chad</option>
          <option value="174">Chile</option>
          <option value="175">China</option>
          <option value="176">Christmas Island</option>
          <option value="177">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
          <option value="178">Colombia</option>
          <option value="179">Comoros</option>
          <option value="180">Congo - Brazzaville</option>
          <option value="181">Congo - Kinshasa</option>
          <option value="182">Cook Islands</option>
          <option value="183">Costa Rica</option>
          <option value="184">Côte d’Ivoire</option>
          <option value="185">Croatia</option>
          <option value="186">Cuba</option>
          <option value="187">Curaçao</option>
          <option value="188">Cyprus</option>
          <option value="189">Czechia</option>
          <option value="190">Denmark</option>
          <option value="191">Djibouti</option>
          <option value="192">Dominica</option>
          <option value="193">Dominican Republic</option>
          <option value="194">Ecuador</option>
          <option value="195">Egypt</option>
          <option value="196">El Salvador</option>
          <option value="197">Equatorial Guinea</option>
          <option value="198">Eritrea</option>
          <option value="199">Estonia</option>
          <option value="200">Eswatini</option>
          <option value="201">Ethiopia</option>
          <option value="202">Falkland Islands</option>
          <option value="203">Faroe Islands</option>
          <option value="204">Fiji</option>
          <option value="205">Finland</option>
          <option value="410">Florida</option>
          <option value="206">France</option>
          <option value="207">French Guiana</option>
          <option value="208">French Polynesia</option>
          <option value="209">French Southern Territories</option>
          <option value="210">Gabon</option>
          <option value="211">Gambia</option>
          <option value="212">Georgia</option>
          <option value="213">Germany</option>
          <option value="214">Ghana</option>
          <option value="215">Gibraltar</option>
          <option value="216">Greece</option>
          <option value="217">Greenland</option>
          <option value="218">Grenada</option>
          <option value="219">Guadeloupe</option>
          <option value="220">Guam</option>
          <option value="221">Guatemala</option>
          <option value="222">Guernsey</option>
          <option value="223">Guinea</option>
          <option value="224">Guinea-Bissau</option>
          <option value="225">Guyana</option>
          <option value="226">Haiti</option>
          <option value="227">Heard &amp; McDonald Islands</option>
          <option value="228">Honduras</option>
          <option value="229">Hong Kong SAR China</option>
          <option value="230">Hungary</option>
          <option value="231">Iceland</option>
          <option value="232">India</option>
          <option value="233">Indonesia</option>
          <option value="234">Iran</option>
          <option value="235">Iraq</option>
          <option value="236">Ireland</option>
          <option value="237">Isle of Man</option>
          <option value="238">Israel</option>
          <option value="239">Italy</option>
          <option value="240">Jamaica</option>
          <option value="241">Japan</option>
          <option value="242">Jersey</option>
          <option value="243">Jordan</option>
          <option value="244">Kazakhstan</option>
          <option value="245">Kenya</option>
          <option value="246">Kiribati</option>
          <option value="247">Kuwait</option>
          <option value="248">Kyrgyzstan</option>
          <option value="249">Laos</option>
          <option value="250">Latvia</option>
          <option value="251">Lebanon</option>
          <option value="252">Lesotho</option>
          <option value="253">Liberia</option>
          <option value="254">Libya</option>
          <option value="255">Liechtenstein</option>
          <option value="256">Lithuania</option>
          <option value="257">Luxembourg</option>
          <option value="258">Macao SAR China</option>
          <option value="259">Madagascar</option>
          <option value="260">Malawi</option>
          <option value="265">Malawi</option>
          <option value="261">Malaysia</option>
          <option value="262">Maldives</option>
          <option value="263">Mali</option>
          <option value="264">Malta</option>
          <option value="266">Marshall Islands</option>
          <option value="267">Martinique</option>
          <option value="268">Mauritania</option>
          <option value="269">Mauritius</option>
          <option value="270">Mayotte</option>
          <option value="271">Mexico</option>
          <option value="272">Micronesia</option>
          <option value="273">Moldova</option>
          <option value="274">Monaco</option>
          <option value="275">Mongolia</option>
          <option value="276">Montenegro</option>
          <option value="277">Montserrat</option>
          <option value="278">Morocco</option>
          <option value="279">Mozambique</option>
          <option value="280">Myanmar (Burma)</option>
          <option value="281">Namibia</option>
          <option value="282">Nauru</option>
          <option value="283">Nepal</option>
          <option value="284">Netherlands</option>
          <option value="285">New Caledonia</option>
          <option value="411">New York</option>
          <option value="286">New Zealand</option>
          <option value="287">Nicaragua</option>
          <option value="288">Niger</option>
          <option value="289">Nigeria</option>
          <option value="290">Niue</option>
          <option value="291">Norfolk Island</option>
          <option value="423">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="292">North Korea</option>
          <option value="293">North Macedonia</option>
          <option value="294">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
          <option value="295">Norway</option>
          <option value="296">Oman</option>
          <option value="412">Oregon</option>
          <option value="297">Pakistan</option>
          <option value="298">Palau</option>
          <option value="299">Palestinian Territories</option>
          <option value="300">Panama</option>
          <option value="301">Papua New Guinea</option>
          <option value="302">Paraguay</option>
          <option value="303">Peru</option>
          <option value="304">Philippines</option>
          <option value="305">Pitcairn Islands</option>
          <option value="306">Poland</option>
          <option value="424">Portland</option>
          <option value="307">Portugal</option>
          <option value="308">Puerto Rico</option>
          <option value="309">Qatar</option>
          <option value="403">Remote</option>
          <option value="310">Réunion</option>
          <option value="311">Romania</option>
          <option value="312">Russia</option>
          <option value="313">Rwanda</option>
          <option value="314">Samoa</option>
          <option value="415">San Francisco</option>
          <option value="315">San Marino</option>
          <option value="316">São Tomé &amp; Príncipe</option>
          <option value="317">Saudi Arabia</option>
          <option value="318">Senegal</option>
          <option value="319">Serbia</option>
          <option value="320">Serbia</option>
          <option value="321">Seychelles</option>
          <option value="417">Shanghai</option>
          <option value="322">Sierra Leone</option>
          <option value="323">Singapore</option>
          <option value="324">Sint Maarten</option>
          <option value="325">Slovakia</option>
          <option value="326">Slovenia</option>
          <option value="327">Solomon Islands</option>
          <option value="328">Solomon Islands</option>
          <option value="329">Somalia</option>
          <option value="330">South Africa</option>
          <option value="331">South Georgia &amp; South Sandwich Islands</option>
          <option value="332">South Korea</option>
          <option value="333">South Sudan</option>
          <option value="334">Spain</option>
          <option value="335">Sri Lanka</option>
          <option value="336">St. Barthélemy</option>
          <option value="337">St. Helena</option>
          <option value="338">St. Kitts &amp; Nevis</option>
          <option value="339">St. Lucia</option>
          <option value="340">St. Martin</option>
          <option value="341">St. Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option>
          <option value="342">St. Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
          <option value="343">Sudan</option>
          <option value="344">Suriname</option>
          <option value="345">Svalbard &amp; Jan Mayen</option>
          <option value="346">Sweden</option>
          <option value="347">Switzerland</option>
          <option value="348">Syria</option>
          <option value="349">Taiwan</option>
          <option value="350">Tajikistan</option>
          <option value="351">Tanzania</option>
          <option value="352">Thailand</option>
          <option value="360">Thailand</option>
          <option value="353">Timor-Leste</option>
          <option value="355">Togo</option>
          <option value="356">Tokelau</option>
          <option value="357">Tonga</option>
          <option value="358">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
          <option value="359">Tunisia</option>
          <option value="361">Turkey</option>
          <option value="362">Turkmenistan</option>
          <option value="363">Turks &amp; Caicos Islands</option>
          <option value="365">Tuvalu</option>
          <option value="366">Tuvalu</option>
          <option value="367">U.S. Outlying Islands</option>
          <option value="369">U.S. Virgin Islands</option>
          <option value="370">Uganda</option>
          <option value="372">Ukraine</option>
          <option value="373">United Arab Emirates</option>
          <option value="374">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="375">United States</option>
          <option value="376">Uruguay</option>
          <option value="377">Uzbekistan</option>
          <option value="418">Vancouver</option>
          <option value="378">Vanuatu</option>
          <option value="379">Vatican City</option>
          <option value="380">Venezuela</option>
          <option value="381">Vietnam</option>
          <option value="382">Wallis &amp; Futuna</option>
          <option value="407">Washington</option>
          <option value="383">Western Sahara</option>
          <option value="384">Yemen</option>
          <option value="385">Zambia</option>
          <option value="386">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select>

        <img src="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/search-triangle.svg" class="search-triangle" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group bordered">
        <label for="years-of-experience" class="sr-only">Company</label>

        <select name="years-of-experience" id="years-of-experience" tabindex="5">
          <option value="">Years of experience</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10+">10+</option>
        </select>

        <img src="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/search-triangle.svg" class="search-triangle" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="guilds">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_status" value="publish">
        <input type="hidden" name="posts_per_page" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="columns" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="offset" value="">

        <button class="btn-submit">
          <img src="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/search-icon.svg" data-searching="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/cog.svg" alt="">

          <span class="btn-text">Search</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Because you have no elements that match `.form-group.bordered:last-child`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

Comment: @CBroe Hey, I couldn't understand how to take that logic and implement it here.
No elements matching `.form-group.bordered:last-child` - I know that's why it doesn't work but I don't understand why, I thought that `.someClass:last-child` is simply going to select the last element of that class.

Comment: _“I thought that `.someClass:last-child` is simply going to select the last element of that class”_ - it doesn’t, and the duplicate I referred you to, explains why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not working because your last-child in your `.form-search` is a not bordered class. If you delete (just for demonstration) your last form-group class (the button) you will see your expected result.

You could change your code to following (focus the 2nd last child's select, with `#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:nth-last-child(2) select`):

```css
/*
 * Search
 */
#top {
  max-width: 1182px;
}

#top .search-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#top .search-wrapper .text {
  margin-right: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#top .form-search {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#top .form-search .form-group {
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

#top .form-search .form-group:last-child {
  max-width: 130px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#top .form-search select,
#top .form-search input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  border-radius: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  background-image: initial;
  color: #515151;
}

#top .form-search select:focus,
#top .form-search select:active,
#top .form-search input:focus,
#top .form-search input:active {
  border-color: #aaaaaa;
}

#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:first-child select,
#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:first-child input {
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
}

#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:nth-last-child(2) select,
#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:last-child input {
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}

#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:not(:last-child) select,
#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:not(:last-child) input {
  border-right: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
}

#top .form-search img.search-triangle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: 15px;
}

#top .form-search .btn-submit {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  float: right;
  height: 43px;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f5af18;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #f5af18;
  color: white;
}

#top .form-search .btn-submit:focus,
#top .form-search .btn-submit:active {
  outline: 0;
}

#top .form-search .btn-submit[disabled] {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

#top .load-more-posts img,
#top .form-search .btn-submit img {
  width: 27px;
  height: 27px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

#top .form-search .btn-submit .btn-text {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="top">
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <div class="text">Search position by</div>

    <form class="form-search" data-post_type="guilds">
      <div class="form-group bordered">
        <label for="keyword" class="sr-only">Keyword</label>

        <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword" placeholder="Keyword" tabindex="1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group bordered">
        <label for="professional-types" class="sr-only">Professional type</label>

        <select name="professional-types" id="professional-types" tabindex="2">
          <option value="">Professional type</option>
          <option value="425">3D Developer</option>
          <option value="395">3D modeling specialist</option>
          <option value="404">3D Project Manager</option>
          <option value="420">3D Specialist</option>
          <option value="402">3D Technical Designer</option>
          <option value="416">CAD Designer</option>
          <option value="391">Fashion designer</option>
          <option value="393">Graphic designer</option>
          <option value="392">Pattern maker</option>
          <option value="408">Product Developer</option>
          <option value="422">Rendering Specialist</option>
          <option value="413">technical developer</option>
        </select>

        <img src="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/search-triangle.svg" class="search-triangle" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group bordered">
        <label for="employment-types" class="sr-only">Employment type</label>

        <select name="employment-types" id="employment-types" tabindex="3">
          <option value="">Employment type</option>
          <option value="389">Freelance</option>
          <option value="387">Full time</option>
          <option value="419">Internship</option>
          <option value="390">None</option>
          <option value="388">Part time</option>
        </select>

        <img src="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/search-triangle.svg" class="search-triangle" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group bordered">
        <label for="locations" class="sr-only">Location</label>

        <select name="locations" id="locations" tabindex="4">
          <option value="">Location</option>
          <option value="129">Afghanistan</option>
          <option value="130">Åland Islands</option>
          <option value="131">Albania</option>
          <option value="132">Algeria</option>
          <option value="133">American Samoa</option>
          <option value="134">Andorra</option>
          <option value="135">Angola</option>
          <option value="136">Anguilla</option>
          <option value="137">Antarctica</option>
          <option value="138">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option>
          <option value="139">Argentina</option>
          <option value="140">Armenia</option>
          <option value="141">Aruba</option>
          <option value="142">Australia</option>
          <option value="143">Austria</option>
          <option value="144">Azerbaijan</option>
          <option value="145">Bahamas</option>
          <option value="146">Bahrain</option>
          <option value="147">Bangladesh</option>
          <option value="148">Barbados</option>
          <option value="149">Belarus</option>
          <option value="150">Belgium</option>
          <option value="151">Belize</option>
          <option value="152">Benin</option>
          <option value="153">Bermuda</option>
          <option value="154">Bhutan</option>
          <option value="155">Bolivia</option>
          <option value="156">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option>
          <option value="414">Boston</option>
          <option value="157">Botswana</option>
          <option value="158">Bouvet Island</option>
          <option value="159">Brazil</option>
          <option value="160">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
          <option value="161">British Virgin Islands</option>
          <option value="162">Brunei</option>
          <option value="163">Bulgaria</option>
          <option value="164">Burkina Faso</option>
          <option value="165">Burundi</option>
          <option value="409">California</option>
          <option value="166">Cambodia</option>
          <option value="167">Cameroon</option>
          <option value="168">Canada</option>
          <option value="169">Cape Verde</option>
          <option value="170">Caribbean Netherlands</option>
          <option value="171">Cayman Islands</option>
          <option value="172">Central African Republic</option>
          <option value="173">Chad</option>
          <option value="174">Chile</option>
          <option value="175">China</option>
          <option value="176">Christmas Island</option>
          <option value="177">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
          <option value="178">Colombia</option>
          <option value="179">Comoros</option>
          <option value="180">Congo - Brazzaville</option>
          <option value="181">Congo - Kinshasa</option>
          <option value="182">Cook Islands</option>
          <option value="183">Costa Rica</option>
          <option value="184">Côte d’Ivoire</option>
          <option value="185">Croatia</option>
          <option value="186">Cuba</option>
          <option value="187">Curaçao</option>
          <option value="188">Cyprus</option>
          <option value="189">Czechia</option>
          <option value="190">Denmark</option>
          <option value="191">Djibouti</option>
          <option value="192">Dominica</option>
          <option value="193">Dominican Republic</option>
          <option value="194">Ecuador</option>
          <option value="195">Egypt</option>
          <option value="196">El Salvador</option>
          <option value="197">Equatorial Guinea</option>
          <option value="198">Eritrea</option>
          <option value="199">Estonia</option>
          <option value="200">Eswatini</option>
          <option value="201">Ethiopia</option>
          <option value="202">Falkland Islands</option>
          <option value="203">Faroe Islands</option>
          <option value="204">Fiji</option>
          <option value="205">Finland</option>
          <option value="410">Florida</option>
          <option value="206">France</option>
          <option value="207">French Guiana</option>
          <option value="208">French Polynesia</option>
          <option value="209">French Southern Territories</option>
          <option value="210">Gabon</option>
          <option value="211">Gambia</option>
          <option value="212">Georgia</option>
          <option value="213">Germany</option>
          <option value="214">Ghana</option>
          <option value="215">Gibraltar</option>
          <option value="216">Greece</option>
          <option value="217">Greenland</option>
          <option value="218">Grenada</option>
          <option value="219">Guadeloupe</option>
          <option value="220">Guam</option>
          <option value="221">Guatemala</option>
          <option value="222">Guernsey</option>
          <option value="223">Guinea</option>
          <option value="224">Guinea-Bissau</option>
          <option value="225">Guyana</option>
          <option value="226">Haiti</option>
          <option value="227">Heard &amp; McDonald Islands</option>
          <option value="228">Honduras</option>
          <option value="229">Hong Kong SAR China</option>
          <option value="230">Hungary</option>
          <option value="231">Iceland</option>
          <option value="232">India</option>
          <option value="233">Indonesia</option>
          <option value="234">Iran</option>
          <option value="235">Iraq</option>
          <option value="236">Ireland</option>
          <option value="237">Isle of Man</option>
          <option value="238">Israel</option>
          <option value="239">Italy</option>
          <option value="240">Jamaica</option>
          <option value="241">Japan</option>
          <option value="242">Jersey</option>
          <option value="243">Jordan</option>
          <option value="244">Kazakhstan</option>
          <option value="245">Kenya</option>
          <option value="246">Kiribati</option>
          <option value="247">Kuwait</option>
          <option value="248">Kyrgyzstan</option>
          <option value="249">Laos</option>
          <option value="250">Latvia</option>
          <option value="251">Lebanon</option>
          <option value="252">Lesotho</option>
          <option value="253">Liberia</option>
          <option value="254">Libya</option>
          <option value="255">Liechtenstein</option>
          <option value="256">Lithuania</option>
          <option value="257">Luxembourg</option>
          <option value="258">Macao SAR China</option>
          <option value="259">Madagascar</option>
          <option value="260">Malawi</option>
          <option value="265">Malawi</option>
          <option value="261">Malaysia</option>
          <option value="262">Maldives</option>
          <option value="263">Mali</option>
          <option value="264">Malta</option>
          <option value="266">Marshall Islands</option>
          <option value="267">Martinique</option>
          <option value="268">Mauritania</option>
          <option value="269">Mauritius</option>
          <option value="270">Mayotte</option>
          <option value="271">Mexico</option>
          <option value="272">Micronesia</option>
          <option value="273">Moldova</option>
          <option value="274">Monaco</option>
          <option value="275">Mongolia</option>
          <option value="276">Montenegro</option>
          <option value="277">Montserrat</option>
          <option value="278">Morocco</option>
          <option value="279">Mozambique</option>
          <option value="280">Myanmar (Burma)</option>
          <option value="281">Namibia</option>
          <option value="282">Nauru</option>
          <option value="283">Nepal</option>
          <option value="284">Netherlands</option>
          <option value="285">New Caledonia</option>
          <option value="411">New York</option>
          <option value="286">New Zealand</option>
          <option value="287">Nicaragua</option>
          <option value="288">Niger</option>
          <option value="289">Nigeria</option>
          <option value="290">Niue</option>
          <option value="291">Norfolk Island</option>
          <option value="423">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="292">North Korea</option>
          <option value="293">North Macedonia</option>
          <option value="294">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
          <option value="295">Norway</option>
          <option value="296">Oman</option>
          <option value="412">Oregon</option>
          <option value="297">Pakistan</option>
          <option value="298">Palau</option>
          <option value="299">Palestinian Territories</option>
          <option value="300">Panama</option>
          <option value="301">Papua New Guinea</option>
          <option value="302">Paraguay</option>
          <option value="303">Peru</option>
          <option value="304">Philippines</option>
          <option value="305">Pitcairn Islands</option>
          <option value="306">Poland</option>
          <option value="424">Portland</option>
          <option value="307">Portugal</option>
          <option value="308">Puerto Rico</option>
          <option value="309">Qatar</option>
          <option value="403">Remote</option>
          <option value="310">Réunion</option>
          <option value="311">Romania</option>
          <option value="312">Russia</option>
          <option value="313">Rwanda</option>
          <option value="314">Samoa</option>
          <option value="415">San Francisco</option>
          <option value="315">San Marino</option>
          <option value="316">São Tomé &amp; Príncipe</option>
          <option value="317">Saudi Arabia</option>
          <option value="318">Senegal</option>
          <option value="319">Serbia</option>
          <option value="320">Serbia</option>
          <option value="321">Seychelles</option>
          <option value="417">Shanghai</option>
          <option value="322">Sierra Leone</option>
          <option value="323">Singapore</option>
          <option value="324">Sint Maarten</option>
          <option value="325">Slovakia</option>
          <option value="326">Slovenia</option>
          <option value="327">Solomon Islands</option>
          <option value="328">Solomon Islands</option>
          <option value="329">Somalia</option>
          <option value="330">South Africa</option>
          <option value="331">South Georgia &amp; South Sandwich Islands</option>
          <option value="332">South Korea</option>
          <option value="333">South Sudan</option>
          <option value="334">Spain</option>
          <option value="335">Sri Lanka</option>
          <option value="336">St. Barthélemy</option>
          <option value="337">St. Helena</option>
          <option value="338">St. Kitts &amp; Nevis</option>
          <option value="339">St. Lucia</option>
          <option value="340">St. Martin</option>
          <option value="341">St. Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option>
          <option value="342">St. Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option>
          <option value="343">Sudan</option>
          <option value="344">Suriname</option>
          <option value="345">Svalbard &amp; Jan Mayen</option>
          <option value="346">Sweden</option>
          <option value="347">Switzerland</option>
          <option value="348">Syria</option>
          <option value="349">Taiwan</option>
          <option value="350">Tajikistan</option>
          <option value="351">Tanzania</option>
          <option value="352">Thailand</option>
          <option value="360">Thailand</option>
          <option value="353">Timor-Leste</option>
          <option value="355">Togo</option>
          <option value="356">Tokelau</option>
          <option value="357">Tonga</option>
          <option value="358">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option>
          <option value="359">Tunisia</option>
          <option value="361">Turkey</option>
          <option value="362">Turkmenistan</option>
          <option value="363">Turks &amp; Caicos Islands</option>
          <option value="365">Tuvalu</option>
          <option value="366">Tuvalu</option>
          <option value="367">U.S. Outlying Islands</option>
          <option value="369">U.S. Virgin Islands</option>
          <option value="370">Uganda</option>
          <option value="372">Ukraine</option>
          <option value="373">United Arab Emirates</option>
          <option value="374">United Kingdom</option>
          <option value="375">United States</option>
          <option value="376">Uruguay</option>
          <option value="377">Uzbekistan</option>
          <option value="418">Vancouver</option>
          <option value="378">Vanuatu</option>
          <option value="379">Vatican City</option>
          <option value="380">Venezuela</option>
          <option value="381">Vietnam</option>
          <option value="382">Wallis &amp; Futuna</option>
          <option value="407">Washington</option>
          <option value="383">Western Sahara</option>
          <option value="384">Yemen</option>
          <option value="385">Zambia</option>
          <option value="386">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select>

        <img src="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/search-triangle.svg" class="search-triangle" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group bordered">
        <label for="years-of-experience" class="sr-only">Company</label>

        <select name="years-of-experience" id="years-of-experience" tabindex="5">
          <option value="">Years of experience</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10+">10+</option>
        </select>

        <img src="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/search-triangle.svg" class="search-triangle" alt="">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="guilds">
        <input type="hidden" name="post_status" value="publish">
        <input type="hidden" name="posts_per_page" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="columns" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="offset" value="">

        <button class="btn-submit">
          <img src="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/search-icon.svg" data-searching="https://browzwear.com/wp-content/themes/enfold-child/img/cog.svg" alt="">

          <span class="btn-text">Search</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @J4R - I've never seen nth-last-child before, do you mind explaining about it?
I thought that if i'm using `.form-group.bordered:last-child` it's going to find the last child with that class! this is not how it works?
Thanks!

Comment: your correct,`.form-group.bordered:last-child` is going to the find the last class with that name, but only if its the last element in the child list.
I created a example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/tcu71nh9/4/

Comment: it's kinda consufing and not working like you expect.. i ran into this very often

Comment: Ah! So so why not just remove `.form-group` for that and just leave `.bordered` for example? shouldn't that work as well?

Comment: not 100% sure what u mean, but your problem is, that the last element in your search-form is the button.
so "last-child select" is never "true", the last child is always the button currently.
It's not important if it's has a class or not

Comment: I mean this: `#top .form-search .bordered:last-child select` - it's the last child of the bordered class

Comment: yes and no :D. it's the last child with this class yes, but it's not last child of `.form-search` and thats the point. It would work if the real last element of `.form-search` would be `#top .form-search .bordered`.

Try to think like this: 
in case your last child element of `.form-search` has the class XX, XX would be selected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233414/discussion-between-odedta-and-j4r).

Answer (score -1):

Just replace ":last-child" with ":nth-child(5)"

```
#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:nth- 
child(5) select,
#top .form-search .form-group.bordered:last-child 
input {
border-top-right-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not going to work when the form fields number is dynamic.

Answer (score -2):

Add this css on your code

```
select#years-of-experience {
border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0 !important;}
```

Comment: This is not a general solution, would not work with different order of fields. Thanks.